# How wrap to new line while using echo?

Tags: php, mysql

The following code...

```
echo "<table width=585 height=182 cass=table1>
<tr>
<td height=10 colspan=3 align=left valign=top></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height=17 colspan=3 align=center valign=middle class=text6>". $data['pgmtitle'] ."
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height=17 colspan=3 align=center valign=middle class=text8>". $data['org'] ."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height=21 colspan=3 align=center valign=middle class=text19>". $data['eventdtls'] ."
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=190 height=28 align=left valign=top class=text3>". $data['venue'] ."</td>
<td width=11 rowspan=2 align=left valign=top><div class=box2></div></td>
<td width=368 rowspan=2 align=left valign=top class=text7>
<b>Contact:</b> ". $data['contactperson'] ."
<br/><b>Phone:</b> ". $data['contactnumber'] ."
<br/><b>E-mail ID:</b> ". $data['email'] ."
<br/><b>Website:</b> ". $data['website'] ."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height=51 align=left valign=top class=text7>". $data['hr'] .":". $data['min'] ." ". $data['time'] ."<br/>". $data['nature'] ."<br/><b>Category:</b> ". $data['category'] ."    
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height=8 colspan=3 align=left valign=top><div class=box3></div></td>
</tr>
</table><br/>";
}
```

I have a registration page and it goes to a database. And this is the retrieving page. If somebody enters 'pgmtitle' without space or fully in capital letter, the echo table is collapsing. Please help me.

Comment: ` the echo table is collapsing.`? how? echo is a STDOUT utility and tables are for HTML... how can you combine them both?

Comment: @Coding: `echo` in a PHP web script will output to the browser.

Comment: But it also outputs to the Standard output stream i guess... isnt it?

Comment: I think the bigger problem here is that you are echoing all that html when you could just echo the $data array attributes.

Comment: Side note: if the value of `$data` can in any way come from the user then you are vulnerable to an XSS exploit here. You should enclose all user date in `htmlspecialchars` on output.

Comment: codingfreak... then how will i style the echo?

Comment: in the table element, you've got `cass=table1`... should it be `class=table1`?

Answer (score 1):

If new lines are giving you problems (it's hard to tell what from your question) you could remove trailing new lines using:

```
$data = array_map("trim", $data);
```

The way you're using `echo()` is pretty horrible. Try to keep presentation (display of HTML) separate from other logic. You could make the code look far cleaner by using `<?php echo $foo ?>` or if you have short tags enabled `<?= $foo ?>`

```
<table width=585 height=182 cass=table1>
<tr>
<td height=10 colspan=3 align=left valign=top></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height=17 colspan=3 align=center valign=middle class=text6><?php echo $data['pgmtitle'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height=17 colspan=3 align=center valign=middle class=text8><?php echo $data['org'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height=21 colspan=3 align=center valign=middle class=text19><?php echo $data['eventdtls'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=190 height=28 align=left valign=top class=text3><? $data['venue'] ?></td>
<td width=11 rowspan=2 align=left valign=top><div class=box2></div></td>
<td width=368 rowspan=2 align=left valign=top class=text7>
<b>Contact:</b><?php echo $data['contactperson'] ?>
<br/><b>Phone:</b> <?php echo $data['contactnumber'] ?>
<br/><b>E-mail ID:</b> <?php echo $data['email'] ?>
<br/><b>Website:</b> <?php echo $data['website'] ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td height=51 align=left valign=top class=text7><?php echo $data['hr'] ?>:<?php echo $data['min'] ?> <?php echo $data['time'] ?><br/><?php echo $data['nature'] ?><br/><b>Category:</b> <?php echo $data['category'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height=8 colspan=3 align=left valign=top><div class=box3></div></td>
</tr>
</table><br/>
```

edit: to answer the further question about iterating:

You can either do:

```
foreach ($rows as $data) {
?>
...
<td><?php echo $foo ?></td>
...
<?php
}
```

or if you're using pretty short tags:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $data) : ?>
...
<td><?= $foo ?></td>
...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

For maintainability and readability it's key that you separate the display logic out.

Comment: Good answer +1. Though even if short tags are enabled I wouldn't advocate their usage.

Comment: Means I am using SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date = '$mydate' AND country = 'Japan'"

Comment: I've edited the answer to include some examples of iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using any quote in the tag attributes?

`class="text7"` for example?

To output them via echo you would have to escaple them using the "\" characater ... like so ...

```
class=\"test7\"
```

Answer (score 0):

are you asking for this http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.wordwrap.php ?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<table><tr><td>".wordwrap($data['pgmtitle'],20,"<br>",true)."</td></tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a HTML & CSS problem, not a PHP problem.

Enclose the `$data['pgmtitle']` in a DIV tag and set its CSS overflow property to hidden.

If you want to modify the TD tag itself, feel free to consult [Why does overflow:hidden not work in a <td>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td)