# How to make table cell not expand when theres text in it?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

If I have a table with only 1 cell, and I set its width and height in its inline style to be a certain amount of pixels (fixed not percentage). What CSS property or attribute is there that will ensure the dimensions on the cell does not increase no matter how much content there is in it. I noticed on my cell, that when I add text, the dimensions still change even though I set it.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `overflow` property. In this case, it seems you want it `hidden`:

```
.cell1 {overflow: hidden;}
```

[Read here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) for more options.

Also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td) post indicating that you need to add `table-layout: fixed;` and `white-space: nowrap;` in addition to the `overflow` property.

Answer (score 3):

Set the table-layout to fixed and the overflow to hidden.

```
table {
    overflow:hidden;
    table-layout:fixed;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nu4Mf/1/)**