# How can I hide overflow in a <td>?

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

I have a table. Its `<td>` have `overflow: hidden`. When I have a string that is longer than 100px, it is not hidden.

How can I hide content when it exceeds the width of its `<td>` container?

http://jsfiddle.net/be6tM/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does overflow:hidden not work in a <td>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td)

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis` [is also fun](http://jsfiddle.net/be6tM/8/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behaviour is just to wrap the text, since height is no issue! You can disable text wrapping, though, with `white-space: nowrap`.

Because tables are a bit of a special case, however, you then need to use `max-width` instead of `width` (which is just a “preferred width”). [Here’s your updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/be6tM/2/)

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no overflow. Set the height in order to restrict the height of the cell, then anything that uses up more vertical space than that should overflow.