# how to fix same image sizes in the table (without oppressed image)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

for setting width there's no problem, but when uploading a portrait image it looks annoying & I want all the images have same width & height, but keeping the image looks good (not stretced/oppressed). maybe like facebook photo profile in timeline ,

and it's my problem : https://d8e7ec01-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/vanyfiles/1-horz.jpg

my html code :

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td id="thumb_img">
         <img src="images/e-magz.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
      </td>
      <td id="thumb_news">
         <div id="date">February 7,2013</div>
         <a href="#">This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

my css code :

```
#thumb_news{
   padding: 5px;
}

#thumb_img{
   width: 25%;
   height: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must try to make another wrapper for your images, and define some width and height do you want, :)
and don't forget img don't have height=100% :D just delete it

HTML

`

```
  <td id="thumb_img">
      <div class="wrap_img">         
          <img src="http://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1463202_599544233439021_1446517358_n.jpg"  width="100%"/>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td id="thumb_news">
     <div id="date">February 7,2013</div>
     <a href="#">This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh</a>
  </td>
```

`

CSS

`.wrap_img{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}`

check this http://jsfiddle.net/a9un9hari/svbSG/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

**The below information is helpful if you are using DIVs but not for tables**

You have `width="100%` and `height="100%` inline in your `<img>` tag. This is forcing the image to BE the width and height of the containing `div`, but that's not what you want.

Try leaving just the width, and you might put it into your CSS, e.g.:

```
.thumb_img img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The height will sort itself out. You already have overflow: hidden on the DIV.

Note that I was using `.thumb_img` not `#thumb_img`—that's for `<td CLASS="thumb_img">` not `<td ID="thumb_img">`. If you are doing thumbs, then likely you are doing more than one. And [CSS IDs must only be used for one element on a page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp).

**FOR TABLES**

You will need to set a width on the table, and `table-layout: fixed` on the TABLE element, for this to work, according to [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td).

If possible I would recommend using DIVs for a situation like this, as they are much more malleable to various layout needs.