# Firefox overflow:hidden not working as it does in Chrome/IE

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to achieve cross-browser functionality for a drag/drop input file, i've come pretty close but this last thing i can't quite figure out. As the title says, it's working just fine in Chrome / IE but in firefox it's not behaving the same. I've left out the drag/drop functionality in my fiddle for simplicity as it's not relevant to the problem.

```
<div class='browseWrapper'>
    Drag & Drop Images Here</br><em>Or click to browse.</em>
    <input class='browseImage' type='file' />
</div>
```

Here's what i've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/sPJ9u/

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sorry i should have been clearer in explaining the problem. If you inspect the input element in firefox you'll see that the overflow:hidden isn't hiding the overflow as it does in Chrome / IE, causing the offset to be out.

Firefox Version: 26

Comment: I see no difference between Chrome and Firefox in your fiddle. What does Firefox do that is undesired?

Comment: And what version of Firefox?

Comment: Layout looks the same as well when inspecting the element

Comment: I still don't actually see the problem. Unrelated, but still issues: use `&amp;` instead of `&` and `<br />` instead of `</br>`

Comment: I'm able to open the file dialog by clicking outside the top/left of the wrapper. Inspecting the elements and clicking between the wrapper and the input clearly shows the problem.. for me at least :S

Comment: Yeah, I figured. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this related question: [Why does overflow:hidden not work in a <td>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td)

It's because you have display set to table-cell, which makes it behave as if the div is actually a td.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this structure in your css:

```
-moz-overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: Why? Firefox has been supporting `overflow:hidden;` for a long time.