# How to create an "overflow: hidden" table column

Tags: html, css

I want my `<table>` to behave normally (height and width changes according to content) but I want a single column that behaves like a "`overflow: hidden`" column in a "`table-layout:fixed;`" table, that means it should have a fixed width and any overflowing content shold be cut off.

Obviously, because I cannot use `table-layout-fixed` because that would affect all columns and not just the one I need to have a fixed width.

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td)

Comment: Isn't it answered there? http://stackoverflow.com/a/509740/483779

Comment: You can use `table-layout: fixed`, just use `nth-child` to apply the width and overflow properties to the table cells in one column [like this example](https://jsbin.com/mefego/edit?css,output)

Answer (score -1):

try using max width on a the column you want to hide overflow

```
<style>
    .hideOverflow {
        max-width: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>

<table style="width:25%">
    <tr>
        <td class="hideOverflow">Jillsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</td>
        <td>Smith</td>      
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If you test this, it doesn't work. The cell stretches.

Comment: I just copy pasted that code into html file and ran it in chrome and worked fine.

Comment: If possible could you explain why its not working on your end? I would be interested to know so i dont make this potential error again. I am not seeing an issue on my side thats all :)

Comment: It *looks* like it works because of the small width. [If you look at this example, with the table stretched at 100%](https://jsbin.com/picudob/edit?html,css,output), the cell stretches :)