# How to make a table cell use overflow hidden?

Tags: html, css

(I cannot use `table-layout:fixed` therefore question [Why does overflow:hidden not work in a ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td) does NOT answer this question)

I have a simple table:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%">main content</td>
        <td style="overflow: hidden;">
            <select name=x>
                <option value=0 selected>A very, very, very, very, very long text in a selection box</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%"></td>
        <td>other content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Basically, the table should give all available space to "main content" and only use as much space as "other content" needs. The selection widget should not cause the column to grow and should instead overflow into hidden.

Unfortunately that does not work (tested in Chrome and Mozilla).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp0xu175/)

Is there a way to do it, if possible without Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does overflow:hidden not work in a <td>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td)

Comment: No, because I cannot use table layout "fixed"

Comment: The whole point is that the first column shall get all the space, thus I need a dynamic table layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "other content" is always short length, you can try `white-space:nowrap`. And set a `min-width` to `select` as needed.

```css
select {
    width: 100%;
    /* min-width: 100px; */
}
td:nth-child(2) {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%">main content</td>
        <td>
            <select name=x>
                <option value=0 selected>A very, very, very, very, very long text in a selection box</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%"></td>
        <td>other content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this style for the select:

```
select { width: 100px; }
```

Comment: Width should be according to "other content" and not a fixed width