# Why doesn't overflow:hidden work on a td?

Tags: html, css, email

I have a table and the `overflow: hidden` property doesn't work, why is that?

```html
<table width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed">
  <tr height="200">
    <td width="100%" height="200" valign="middle" style="text-align: center; overflow: hidden;">
      <img src="http://salesdey.com/product_images/eb235de7eee13a0aa61dae2cc9de1f7e.gif" width="100" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does overflow:hidden not work in a <td>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td)

Comment: @Roberrrt no it's not, I've used the `table-layout: fixed` as pointed out in that answer and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You're missing `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: @Roberrrt that doesn't fix it either.

Comment: Roberrrt, seems thiis not work because he is asking for the height not width...

Comment: I think it doesn't work because content is an image. Not plain text.

Answer (score 0):

According to w3schools : 
The **overflow** property only works for block elements with a specified height.

Since `<div>` is a block element you can try to use that in your `<td>` cell and then apply the property on it.

Also, as commented by @Roberrt this is already answered here in detail.

[Why does overflow:hidden not work in a <td>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td)

Answer (score 0):

Because the contents of a cell never overflow the cell in the Y direction. The cell height will always grow vertically to contain its contents. So there's nothing for the overflow property to do.

Answer (score -2):

`overflow:hidden` not work on table-cell, if you can change the html, you should use a div instead of table.

But if you can do it... Then you should add `display:inline-block` to the td.