# using ellipsis in table

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a table that is using an ellipsis but I'm stuck with conflicting arguements. The scenario is a I have a table with a tr tag and 2 td's. I need the first td to be the width of the text ( border-collapse: collapse ) which is fine, BUT, I need the width of the table to be 100% so in the 2nd td I can use the ellipsis. I haven't found a way to to border-collapse the first td and have the 2nd be used as an ellipsis.

http://jsfiddle.net/epywtvjf/2/

```
   <table>
     <tr>
        <td>This is the first div.
        </td>
        <td>This is the second div. This is the second div.This is the second div. This is the second div. This is the second div.
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>This is the first div.
        </td>
        <td>This is the second div. This is the second div.This is the second div. This is the second div. This is the second div.
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>This is the first div.
        </td>
        <td>This is the second div. This is the second div.This is the second div. This is the second div. This is the second div.
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>

table{
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td{
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: none;
  line-height:unset;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: So you want the first column however wide it needs to be to fit its text, then the second column to just get pushed over, and its contents will be ellipsed if they're too wide?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add display flex to your tr. The following css worked for me.

```
table {
       table-layout: fixed;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       width:100%;
}
tr{
  display: flex; 
}
td{
      white-space: nowrap;
      border: none;
      padding: 0px;
      text-align: left;
      border-collapse: collapse;
}
#td2 {
      overflow:hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krewn/opputmg3/1/

Comment: yes this worked thanks! I didn't even think about flex.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify specific css for each individual td by adding a class to the td in the html and then using the . class selector in css.

```
<table>
         <tr>
            <td class="col1">This is the first div.
            </td>
            <td class="col2">This is the second div. This is the second div.This is the second div. This is the second div. This is the second div.
            </td>
          </tr>
</table>


table {
       table-layout: fixed;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       width: 100%;
}
td{
      white-space: nowrap;
      border: none;
      padding: 0px;
      text-align: left;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      overflow: hidden;
}
.col2 {
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krewn/qcypz5xk/

Comment: What if there are multiple rows? In html id must be unique

Comment: there will be multiple rows

Comment: Why the down-vote? The Op doesn't have multiple rows, regardless you can use class instead of id.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I know I can add a class to the 2nd but it needs to have a width to work and since I can't set a width to it, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Changing table-layout: fixed and overflow:hidden?
Will that solve your issue?
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td)

Comment: the first td tag will vary in length depending on text so I can't set a max-width on anything

Comment: no because I can't make one column a fixed width, it will always be a percentage of the first