# Are there any trick to append ... by CSS?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Let see my problem

I have an element which its width = 50px

and I have my string to put in that element "**This text is longer than 50px and will be display in two or more lines**"

What I want to get in my element is the text with 50px width + ... like this :

**This text is longer than 50px and will...**

Are there any good or possible way to do this with CSS?

Comment: If no one has an answer, you can always do it via PHP by check the strlen of the string, and if it is over X letters, substr it an add "..."

Comment: Letters have different widths so checking the string length wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, but you could compensate for that by going a little under. But there was an answer anyway, so no matter.

Answer (score 2):

There is a CSS property for this, but [it is not supported by Firefox](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t46):

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

There are [hacks](http://www.jide.fr/emulate-text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-with-css) to make it work in Firefox, but none are too pretty.

Some required reading:

- [Ellipsis in all modern browsers](http://ernstdehaan.blogspot.com/2008/10/ellipsis-in-all-modern-browsers.html)
- [Truncating long strings with CSS: feasible yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802175)