# How can I truncate long texts in a table using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone give a CSS example of how can I create a table where long texts are truncated to texts ending with "..."?

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/NpABe/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>ssssssss</td>
        <td>dddddddddddd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ffffffffffffffff</td>
        <td>gggggggggggggggggggg</td>
        <td>hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</td>
        <td>kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</td>
        <td>llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I truncate table cells, but fit as much as content possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239758/how-can-i-truncate-table-cells-but-fit-as-much-as-content-possible)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `text-overflow: ellipsis`. You will need to fix the width of the cells and prevent line wrapping:

```
td {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**EDIT**: actually this won't work.  It seems you need a container div to apply the styles to:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div</td>
(snip)
```

And then:

```
 td div {
   width: 100px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;         
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
```

**EDIT 2**  Ah there is a way, but only if you use `table-layout: fixed`:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100px;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;         /* <- this does seem to be required */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: `overflow` won't work here as `td` elements are `display: table-cell` by default.

Comment: @Rory, yep you're quite right. In fact it doesn't work at all.  Could have sworn I'd done this before, but it seems to be impossible without   an extra div :(

Answer (score 10):

**2021 UPDATE - PURE CSS WORKING VERSION**

The accepted answer wasn't doing the trick for me...

The ONLY way to do it without specifying a `min-width` is achieved by using `line-clamp`.

```
.clamp {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
}
.clamp-2 {
  line-clamp: 2!important;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2!important;
}
.clamp-3 {
  line-clamp: 3!important;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3!important;
}
```

As IE is (Finally) dying-off, and being replaced by Edge, support is now (nearly) global at 96-ish %.

IE support can be achieved by specifying a `max-height` based on `line-height` and `overflow-y: hidden`.

---

### Example

```css
.clamp {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
}
.clamp-2 {
  line-clamp: 2!important;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2!important;
}
.clamp-3 {
  line-clamp: 3!important;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3!important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Context</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <tr>
    <th scope="row">French Revolution</th>
    <td class="clamp clamp-3"><span style="color:red;">Clamp 3 lines</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </td>
    <td>1789</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th scope="row">First Republic</th>
    <td class="clamp clamp-2"><span style="color:red;">Clamp 2 lines</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</td>
    <td class="text-center text-decoration-line-through">1792</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Star Wars: A New Hope</th>
    <td class="clamp clamp-1"><span style="color:red;">Clamp 1 lines</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</td>
    <td>1977</td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

### Learn more

- Caniuse @ https://caniuse.com/#search=line-clamp
- Codepen @ https://codepen.io/amarinediary/full/wvoKdzO

Comment: Edge supports this?

Comment: Since 2021 it is supported by all browser. (As IE getting replaced by Edge). See the [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=line-clamp).

Answer (score 4):

This is a variation on the answer from @RobAgar that works well for me. I define the following CSS:

```
td.item-node {
   max-width: 10em;
}
div.ellipsis {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

And the HTML looks like

```
<td class="item-note">
   <div class="ellipsis">Really super duper long item note that will truncate</div>
</td>
```

This way I can specify the width on the thing I care about (the table cell) without having to repeat all the white-space, overflow CSS properties for each cell.  The class on the div also makes it clear what its purpose is.

Answer (score 1):

You can make truncate class for long text. See below class
[**This works on table td**]

```
 .truncate {
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      max-width: 1px;
    }
```

**Works for others:**

```
.truncate {
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
          overflow: hidden;
          white-space: nowrap;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

css text-overflow: ellipsis;

```css
td {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>ssssssss</td>
        <td>dddddddddddd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ffffffffffffffff</td>
        <td>gggggggggggggggggggg</td>
        <td>hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</td>
        <td>kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</td>
        <td>lllllllllllllllllllllllddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddlllllllllllll</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need truncate text for just one line use this css:

```
.truncate-text-one-line{
    width:80%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Otherwise, use this script:

```
function shorten_text(text, maxLength) {
    var ret = text;
    if (ret.length > maxLength) {
        ret = ret.substr(0,maxLength-3) + "...";
    }
    document.write(ret);
}
```