# How to showing title on two lines in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Suppose I have a long title for some of my posts in my wordpress website.

Now I want to show those long titles in two lines either in desktop or laptop or mobile screen.

That means in all devices that long title shows in two line and then dot(...).

It is possible for specific character but how to do that for specific lines?

Anybody help please?

Comment: checking the length and add some logic could solve your issue.

Comment: This can be achieved with pure css. I've answered this a while back @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/62953318/3645650

Comment: @amarinediary...yours one is correct for me....will you please give it as an answer? I will accept it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with css:

```
.my-long-title {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-clamp: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```