# How can I force all rows in a table to have the same height

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to build a html table but I want to force all rows to have the same height (no matter how much content is in the cells).  If a cell overruns the space, I want it to just cut off the text and hide the rest.

Is this possible using CSS, etc?

Comment: Might be naive, but simple setting of `table td {height:100px;}` doesn't work?

Comment: A small follow up question. Is it possible to have a table where all rows have the same height, but the height is automatically calculated? In other words, all rows are as tall as the tallest row needs to be to accommodate its content?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## IE only

```css
    #fixedheight {
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    
    #fixedheight td {
        height: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 25%;
    }
```

```html
    <table id="fixedheight">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>lots of content that should spend way more time wrapping down than it should if I were just to have a short bit of stuff, that would be invaded by zombies and the such</td>
                <td>more content</td>
                <td>small content</td>
                <td>enough already</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

---

## Universal solution

```css
    #fixedheight {
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    
    #fixedheight td {
        width: 25%;
    }
    
    #fixedheight td div {
        height: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
    <table id="fixedheight">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>content</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>lots of content that should spend way more time wrapping down than it should if I were just to have a short bit of stuff, that would be invaded by zombies and the such</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <div>more content</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <div>small content</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <div>enough already</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <table>
```

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't seem to make it smaller in height than what fits with the content.  een if height: 1px. if there are 3 rows of data (after wrapping), it still shows all 3 rows. it seems that overflow:hidden doesn't seem to be taken affect. i am using firefox

Comment: I did a bunch of research and there is a solution in IE, but not for other browsers.  I've updated the example with IE compliment code and universal code.

Answer (score 3):

Set the CSS `height` property to what you want the cell heights to be, and use `overflow: hidden` (see [CSS overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp)) to prevent contents from expanding the cells.

Comment: i am doing this and it still expands to fit multiple rows of content even if i have height set to 1px; and overflow:hidden ..any thoughts ??

Comment: @ooo, are you setting the styles on the `table` or the `td`?

Comment: You'll probably need white-space: nowrap so that the content doesn't wrap in a cell.

Answer (score 2):

Give the table a class:

```
<table class="myTable">...</table>
```

And in the CSS, try the following:

```
table.myTable td {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @ohmusama - i tried this but it doesn't seem to make it smaller in height than what fits with the content. een if height: 1px. if there are 3 rows of data (after wrapping), it still shows all 3 rows. it seems that overflow:hidden doesn't seem to be taken affect. i am using firefox  . .any ideas??

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554928/how-to-hide-table-row-overflow

Answer (score 1):

The CSS Styles you will want to set are:
display:block, min-height, and max-height.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
          <title>JS Bin</title>
          <style>
            html{font-size:16px;}
            table{}
            table tr{
              display:block;
              border-bottom:solid green 1px;    
              height:.8em;
              min-height:.8em;
              max-height:.8em;
              background-color:#E300E3;
              overflow:hidden;
           }
         </style>
       </head>
       <body>
         <table id="MyTable">
           <tr><td>16px Font-Size</td><td>Column2</td></tr>
         </table>
       </body>
     </html>
```