# How to make all the rows of a table the same height as the biggest one

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to make all the rows of a table the same height as the one that has the longest text in it, expanding accordingly.

But all I achieved is give them a fixed height after reading this:
[How can I force all rows in a table to have the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671098/how-can-i-force-all-rows-in-a-table-to-have-the-same-height)

This means that I need to predict how much text I should put in it which is obviously not predictable.  Is it possible with CSS or do I need using Javascript?

Comment: You would definitely need to use JavaScript to implement conditional behaviour.

Comment: Thanks David so I need to dynamically calculate the height of the rows that has expanded most and give that height to the other rows. I will try and post the result. (sorry for my english)

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Here's a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DqrPB/), which doesn't merit posting as an answer since it's essentially the same as that provided by [Samuel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10701655/82548), below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with pure CSS.

It's possible to do it with javascript. For example, with jQuery you could write something like

```
var maxHeight = null;
$(<MY LINES>).each(function() {
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    if(maxHeight == null || thisHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight = thisHeight;
}).height(maxHeight);
```

Don't forget to handle borderline cases and to include a maximum and a minimum height to your lines.