# html fix first column and same height other columns

Tags: html, css

I want fix first column of table, but I have a problem that if first column has more height than others, then the other columns don't have the same height.

This is my code:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Header A</th>
          <td>col 1 - A</td>
          <td>col 2 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
          <td>col 3 - A</td>
          <td>col 4 - A</td>
          <td>col 5 - A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Header B</th>
          <td>col 1 - B</td>
          <td>col 2 - B</td>
          <td>col 3 - B</td>
          <td>col 4 - B</td>
          <td>col 5 - B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Header C
          Header C
            Header C
            Header C
          </th>
          <td>col 1 - C</td>
          <td>col 2 - C</td>
          <td>col 3 - C</td>
          <td>col 4 - C</td>
          <td>col 5 - C</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

table {
  table-layout: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
  *margin-left: -100px;/*ie7*/
}
td, th {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  width:100px;
}
th {
  position:absolute;
  *position: relative; /*ie7*/
  left:0; 
  width:100px;
}
.outer {position:relative}
.inner {
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:visible;
  width:400px; 
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

Here is an example; how I can resolve it ?

http://jsbin.com/uxecel/4457/edit

I want that row height do the same in all the row, and not fixed because this is dinamic.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean row height? Or column width?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701562/how-to-make-all-the-rows-of-a-table-the-same-height-as-the-biggest-one

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

http://jsfiddle.net/AlexCharlton/5d4yqn7a/1/

Add:

```
height: 80px;
```

To:

```
td, th {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 80px;
  padding:10px;
  width:100px;
}
```

Alternatively, their is this method, where you can apply a class to specific rows/columns like follows..

http://jsfiddle.net/AlexCharlton/5d4yqn7a/2/

HTML:

```
<td class = "Long">col 2 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
```

CSS:

```
td.Long {
   width: 280px;
}
```

Comment: I want that height grow up automatic, if i add more content the problem persist.. It is charged dinamic http://jsfiddle.net/5d4yqn7a/4/

Comment: Just add: Height: auto; ?

Comment: Nvm, That doesn't work, let me have a think how you can resolve that, 2 mins

Comment: I Don't think it's possible with just html and css, you might need to apply some javascript, the solution for html and css only will be just to apply separate classes depending on how high/wide you need each row/column