# How to trim content of element and put "..." if the characters go over a certain limit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to trim a part of the `<td>` if it is too long. This will make sure the table doesn't get messed up. All the data in the following table is retrieved from a database. On the "Subject" part, how could I make the text shorten and put "..." if it goes over a certain character limit? Here is a screenshot of the table:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see if the subject gets too long it may mess up the table.

Is there any jQuery that will make the element trim only if it goes over a certain limit and put "..." at the end? I don't think a truncate plugin would work because it usually splits it up and makes a line break and I don't need it to show because all the person using this would have to do is click "View ticket" and they will see the full subject there.

I searched other questions on StackOverflow but I couldn't find one that is what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little snippet that I used to see if an artists name was over 33 characters

```
// Elipses 
$('.artistName').each(function() {
    var that = $(this),
        title = that.text(),
        chars = title.length;

    if (chars > 33) {
        var newTitle = title.substring(0, 30) + "...";
        that.text(newTitle);
    }
});
```

Just replace the .artistName selector with the one for your table cell and update the character counts to reflect what you want.

Comment: It almost works, but it just adds the "..." after the text but doesn't trim it. I even set it to 5 to see and it didn't work. Maybe there is a little error? Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Do you have some example markup? If its adding the ..., it means its not getting the correct length of the cell contents.

Comment: Here is one of the table row codes: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25819920/my-code.txt The `td` with `class="shorten"` is the part that I am trying to shorten.  Is that what you needed?

Comment: Oh, thanks. Was the problem that I was not putting `td` in the selector? If you look at that file again, I added the JS I was using. Thanks so much!

Comment: the problem was that you were saying IF LESS THAN 5, take chars 0 to 30. You forgot to update the second digit.

Comment: Wow... I feel stupid, LOL. I just noticed I changed the number in the statement and not the substring.

Answer (score 8):

You might be able to use the CSS [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/text-overflow) property.

According to [this compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow), it is supported by all major browsers.

---

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554928/how-to-hide-table-row-overflow/1555073#1555073), it looks like you also need to define `table-layout: fixed` on the table, and `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap` on the cells. The fixed table layout will also require you to adjust your column widths explicitly.

Comment: It seems that the solution is not as simple as just adding `text-overflow` and `width`. Does anybody know how to get this approach to actually work?

Comment: But this doesn't add the ellipsis and I think using jQuery is easier as you don't have to add all the extra CSS. But thanks for answering, I never knew about the `text-overflow: ellipsis` until now.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that will respect word boundaries (it won't split a word in half).

```
var maxLength = 30;

$('.shorten').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();

    if (text.length > maxLength) {
        var output =/^.{0,30}(?=[\.,; ])\b/.exec(text)[0]
        $(this).text(output + "...");
    }     
});
```