# Can someone help me restrict the height of CSS class and add a scrollbar?

Tags: css, html-table, scrollbar, overflow

Sounds easy I know. I told the client it would be done in 5 minutes... 4 hours later it is just getting annoying...

This is the current structure:

```
<div class="RadWindow">
    <table class="rwTable">
        <tr class="rwContentRow">
            <td class="helpDialog"> Content to be cut off and wrapped</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

There is actually a few more styles etc in the div, but these are the ways that I should be able to control it. I have tried setting a height, max-height and overflow on the class .helpDialog, but nothing happens.

I then tried it on the `<td>`:

```
td.helpDialog
```

I then tried stipulating the entire path in a verbose manner:

```
.RadWindow table td.helpDialog
```

It is just not working for me. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I think you're going to have to add a `div` inside the `td` and apply the styles to that. Or perhaps look here: [How to hide Table Row Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554928/how-to-hide-table-row-overflow)

Answer (score 3):

use an extra div container to control the layout.

html:

```
<div class="RadWindow">
    <table class="rwTable">
        <tr class="rwContentRow">
            <td><div class="helpDialog">Content to be cut off and wrapped</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

css:

```
.helpDialog{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

By the way, do not over qualify css selectors. This will slow down your page rendering especial on large dom trees and/or dynamic sites.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll try this and hopefully that will fix it. Hopefully I am able to change it (it being created by a Telerik control)...