# Force <tr> height with CSS

Tags: css, html-table

I need to control the height of a table row--I have tried setting the height of the cells, but I'm hitting a brick wall. [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EUFxM/4/).

```
tr.fixedRow,
tr.fixedRow td.fixedCell {
     height: 50px;
     overflow: hidden; }
```

I know that I could change the `display` of some things to `block` but doing so generally messes up the table in a bad way--I'm working with a rather complicated table that interacts with other tables nearby and needs to line up pixel-perfectly, so generally, changing the `display` and then trying to make it look like a table again with CSS isn't a good solution for me, because it won't match up. I need it to stay a table.

I also want to avoid doing this:

```
<td><div>
   ... cell content...
</div></td>
```

Which seems like terrible form. Surely there is a CSS only solution to something so simple?

Comment: AFAIK, you can force a height with the HTML height attribute...

Comment: @A.M.K [Doesn't look like it.](http://jsfiddle.net/EUFxM/5/)

Comment: Haven't checked, but this looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554928/how-to-hide-table-row-overflow#answer-1555073

Comment: @mayhewr that one is close, but he wanted the table to be one row, and the answers all reflect that (e.g. use of `white-space:nowrap;` or controlling the width to make the heights match up). I am looking to give a row an arbitrary height, so solutions to that question won't help me much.

Comment: Do you need the width of the column to be determined ahead of time?  If not, you could set it to some percentage and set the cell to `position:relative` and put a div inside it that has `width:100%;position:absolute`.  Would that work?

Comment: @mayhewr you might be on to something with the use of `position`, but if I'm going to nest a `<div>` under the `<td>`s, then all I need to make it work the way I want is `.fixedCell > div {height:50px;overflow:hidden;}`.

Comment: Oh. I totally missed that part of your question, sorry. I don't think that's *that* terrible.  It is dumb that the `height` CSS property doesn't work on `td`s or `tr`s with overflow, I totally agree, but if that nested `div` works, it works. :)

Comment: It's not terrible at all - it's bad form to use unnecessary elements, but this isn't one. Part of the reason the `td` element doesn't accept straight height/overflow declarations is that the height isn't independent: it is affected by the other cells in the row. Parsing both the content and the CSS, and respecting widths/heights like a block element would be really complex.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are trying to achieve this by relying on a css property that does not work the way you expect it to: CSS overflow applies to block-level elements, something a `<td>` is not (css: `display: table-cell;`).

see [CSS Overflow on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow)

For this reason, I believe you won't be able to achieve fixed height unless you set `display: block;` on `<td>`s - and you said you can't as it would break the table alignment, so the only sensible alternative would be, in my opinion:

```
<td><span>...</span></td>
```

with your `<span>` set to `display: block;` (doesn't really make a difference to have a span set to block instead of a div, apart from the fact that a `div` would break the html validation, while a span would not - block elements are not allowed in `td` elements)

it's the most elegant and valid way I can think of.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: I don't see why setting the `span` to `display: block;` would keep it from validating...

Comment: indeed, I guess my answer wasn't particularly clear in that section, but what I meant was that having a `div` would throw a validation error; a `span` will not throw such error of course, as it's not a block element - w3c spec and its implementation in validation tool(s) does not care if the `display` property is set to `block` via CSS. I'll amend my answer to make it clearer!