# How to limit table row height to 3 lines?

Tags: html, css

I am having a `table` which is wider than the screen, and some `td`'s also contain a lot of text. How to limit the row `height` to 3 lines (and let the `table` become even wider)?

Here: [How to hide Table Row Overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554928/how-to-hide-table-row-overflow) is a very similar question, except that I need 3 lines not just 1. So `whitespace: nowrap` does not work for me.

I tried `max-height: 3em` on nested `div`s, like this:

```
<td><div>a lot of text...</div></td>
```

but it just causes the `div` contents to clip (the `div`'s `width` remains constant!, even if I set `width: auto` or `width: 100%`).

BTW I don't want `table-layout: fixed`, because I don't want to specify column widths manually.

Thanks!

Comment: create a jfiddle for that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kX63T/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kX63T/3/ check this

Answer (score 0):

why cant you have the **full table as div**, so that you can specify height to the div, and limit the lines of text through *overflow-y:hidden*. simple way other than table.

Comment: Because I am displaying tabular data!

Answer (score -1):

Add the css style `overflow-y: scroll;` to your cell.

[I've updated the JSFiddle below to demonstrate.](http://jsfiddle.net/kX63T/2/)

Comment: I don't want scrollbars, I want the column width to expand!

Comment: If you resize the window on the JSFiddle you'll see that the columns are expanding! There is just too much text. The columns can only expand as much as the width of the screen. The other two columns have already shrunk as much as possible to accommodate third column and its massive text.

Comment: Well but as I said, the `table` is wider than the screen (viewport). I try to emulate it here: http://jsfiddle.net/F6S5J/ . I need the outer `div` to expand its `width` so the `td` scrollbar disappears.