# How to make all divs the same size whether they have content or not?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a battleship game, where there is a generated grid on the board, where each square is a colored box with a number, and is its own div. The problem I'm having is that when one of the divs gets some extra content in it, it makes that particular div longer than the rest of the divs, which throws off the whole grid. How do I make sure all of the divs are the same height no matter if they have extra content or not? I have tried adding a height property to the CSS, but it does not change the actual height of the colored box.

Comment: We need to see the code you tried

Comment: I guess all I need to know is if there is a CSS property that will make all the boxes the same height? I thought that would be height, but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define how overflowing content is handled.

```
.cut-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: what about if the user is using a table ? ;)

Comment: The OP specifically states that she/he uses a 'div'.

Comment: I hope the OP didn't set the div to `display: inline` or `display: table`. That would explain why setting the height has no effect as stated. ;)

Comment: Good point! @Mary I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `height`. You might be fighting specificity. Try the following:

```
.grid_div {
  height: 100px;
  height: 100px!important; /* if the previous does not work */
  max-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px!important; /* if the previous does not work */
  overflow: hidden; /* just for the visual effect */
  display: inline-block; /* choose inline-block or block */
  display: block; /* choose inline-block or block */
}
```

Comment: what about if the user is using a table ? ;)

Comment: Then you go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554928/how-to-hide-table-row-overflow

Comment: Why not, the op should post enough code that shows  the issue, not us to guess what went wrong ;)

Comment: Amen. You are preaching to the choir.