# css - hiding overflow

Tags: css, text, truncate

Is it possible to hide the overflow of the text in say a fixed width div and replace it with "..."? It obviously looks ugly if the text is just cut off, I really need to be able to show a ... in these cases.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802175/truncating-long-strings-with-css-feasible-yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, but it doesn't seem to work in IE6 and Firefox..

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html

Comment: very nice! just what i needed.

Comment: @Joe This is **not** a good solution. `ellipsis` is an IE proprietary value for `overflow`, and doesn't work on any browser other than IE.

Comment: As the page I linked to states (and I have tested this), it works fine in Chrome, Safari, Opera(with '-o-text-overflow') and of course IE7+

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that only with CSS, you have to use either javascript or php.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with css. You'll have to do it with PHP or Javascript. [Here's a decent tutorial](http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2007/08/ellipsis-or-truncate-with-dots-via-javascript/) on doing it with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful

```
$('#customComboBox').text(($.trim($('#customComboBox').text()).length > 19) ? 
    $.trim($('#customComboBox').text()).substring(0, 16) + '...' : 
    $.trim($('#customComboBox').text()));
```

Comment: Not a very good solution - you still need to know how many characters till the text will overflow. Also, the jQuery code can be made much, much, more efficient with some caching.