# Show first line of a paragraph

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a DIV with a multi-line paragraph.

Is there any way (maybe using jQuery) to only show the first line of the paragraph and hide the others?

Comment: jquery works on the DOM/direct elements. a paragraph is an element. lines is a paragraph is not. so i wouldn't think this would be possible.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/a/22811590/759452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>There is not an outright way to do this by specifying the first line.</strike> I would suggest changing the height of the DIV using CSS to only show the first line. It would seem to me to be the simplest solution. If you then want to change to show the whole line with javascript just use it to change the height of the DIV back to 100%.

**EDIT**: I stand corrected, I was not aware that there was a first-line pseudo class. However changing the height may still be the simplest way.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way (sort of) by making the paragraph white-on-white except the :first-line of it: http://jsbin.com/usora4/2/edit

Snippet of CSS:

```
p { color: white; }
p:first-line { color: black; }
```

Comment: yeah this would work, apart from spacing. the p would'nt auto-size, because the contents are still there. so it's hiding the text, but no the actual 'line' (where 'line' refers to a block of space in a paragraph). still, +1. :)

Comment: Good, simple idea. But it still uses the same space as the whole paragraph.

Answer (score 6):

It has been awhile since this was answered but seeing there is no example here is one that works pretty well:

```
<div style="width:200px">
<div>
    This is above the paragraph.
</div>
<div class="excerpt">
    This is my text. It has many lines. This is my text.
    It has many lines.This is my text. It has many lines.
    This is my text. It has many lines. This is my text.
    It has many lines.
</div>
<div>
    This is below the paragraph.
</div>
</div>


<style type="text/css">
div.excerpt { height:2.2em; overflow:hidden; }
div.excerpt:hover { height:auto; }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h82313am/

Comment: As for 2019 using diffrent approaches with nowrap, first-line etc etc, this answer in the context of the question asked -is the way to do it. Would like to add that difffrent font sizes and families jumps on the line-heights. So adding `line-height: 2.2em;` together with the desired height makes it more proof. One good Idea is: `line-height: 1.25em; height: 1.25em;` keeps a nice spaced line, and using `height: 2.5em` then gives you the first two rows.

Answer (score 2):

No need for JavaScript, measuring height, or changing visibility. Just set the paragraph to display inline and not to wrap its text. You'll want to set the overflow on the parent div to "hidden" so the remaining lines in the paragraph don't spill out.

```
#wrap {
    overflow: hidden;   
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
p {
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VvdBs/

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this here as an idea. It allows you to show and hide the text with a text box. CSS only.

```css
p.bar { font-size:0; margin:0;padding:10px;background: #ddd; -webkit-transition: font-size .25s;transition: font-size .25s;
}
p.bar:first-line { font-size:20px; }
input:checked + label  + p.bar {font-size: 20px;}
```

```html
<input id="foo" type="checkbox"><label for="foo">show</label><p class="bar">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Determine the height of your line and set the height of the div such that only one line is shown, and set the div's `overflow` attribute to `hidden`.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it, but you should be able to do a little better using visibility, e.g.

```
<div class="excerpt">
   This is my text.  It has many lines. This is my text.  
   It has many lines. This is my text. It has many lines. 
   This is my text.  It has many lines. This is my text.  
   It has many lines.
</div>
```

and then setting up a style

```
div.excerpt { visibility: hidden; }
div.excerpt:first-line { visibility: visible; }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've tried both visibility and display and couldn't get it to work. Funnily enough, it worked for color. But again it only worked when I've changed from div to p, and introduced a <br> in between the lines...