# How do I limit the length of an link?

Tags: html, css

I have links that I want limit the length. They are inside of an unordered list and they wrap. I want to limit the length of the url instead of having it wrap. Because it is wrapping I can't use overflow:hidden.

Is there a way to limit them the href with css?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802175/truncating-long-strings-with-css-feasible-yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ul li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/9zGV7/).

You can then use `overflow: hidden` on the container.

Altenatively, you can use JavaScript to truncate the strings, and perhaps append an ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

I know you requested a CSS way to do this, but just in case JavaScript is an option you could do something like this:

```
truncate("http://www.thisisaverlylongurl.com/and-i-want/to-truncate-it", 25);

var truncate = function(text, max_chars){    
  return (text.length > max_chars) ? text.substring(0, max_chars) + '...' : text ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the CSS property `overflow: hidden;` can help you, in conjuntion with `width`.