# How to truncate paragragh lines in css

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [With CSS, use “…” for overflowed block of multi-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines)

Is there way to truncate lines of a paragraph in css?
e.g. i have 7 line paragraph, and I want them to truncate into 3 lines.
I have tried this:
    p {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%; }
but it will form 1 line truncated

Comment: You might be able to hack something with `em`s, but I don't think this is possible with just CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/B4w3B/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802175/truncating-long-strings-with-css-feasible-yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css code as

```
p{
height: 50px; //depends up on whatever you want
width: 100%
// add your css code
}
```

Comment: have tried putting height on <p> but still the it displays 1 line <p>,
need it in 3 lines then "..."
is there any css rule i should to achieve 3lines <p> while truncated?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/st8q2/ try this. if it not work add `!important` to every css code.

Comment: have tried you code, but the "..." not working,
is truncate good for 1 line?

Comment: try to add class or id in `p` like this http://jsfiddle.net/st8q2/1/

Comment: In your http://jsfiddle.net/st8q2/1/ yes it forms three lines but the declaration: text-overflow: ellipsis; - not working, no "..." showing up.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines. if you not satisfy, I suggest you to, post this question in new one.