# HTML CSS how to adapt text on a Div's size

Tags: html, css

I want to put a big text into a smal div, and **I want that the div doesn't resizing** but just **doesn't show all the text**.

For exemple the orginal Div's dimension are **height:40px; width:100px;**

**This image will help you to understand what I mean**

[image: http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/2404/9bbs.jpg]

Thanks you

I've tried a lot of ways but didn't works

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802175/truncating-long-strings-with-css-feasible-yet

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? sometimes it's more helpful if we can see your current thought process on how you think this should be solved, then we can steer you back on track, or show you the small mistakes.

Comment: @rlemon don't you think that the "WHAT IT DOES" part in my IMAGE represent what I 've tried ? don't you think ? really ? do you realize what you are asking to me ?

Comment: @user2372006 let me clarify: Have you tried to produce any code to facilitate your needs? If you have we would very much like to take a look at it to see how close to a solution you may be at. If you have not tried any solution then you can also tell us that. Your attitude and (seeming) rage on the entire issue does not bode well for you, and you should probably check that at the door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jquery `dotdotdot` plugin to achieve this for multi lines. If it is for single line then it can be easily done with CSS alone.

```
$("div").dotdotdot()
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9sE6b/1/)**

Here is the **[LINK](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/)** for dotdotdot plugin

Answer (score 3):

Using `text-overflow: ellipsis` will just work on single line text. There's a little trick to fake that with multiple-lines using just CSS: http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

There's also a nice jQuery plug-in just in case you are using jQuery: http://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 'overflow' property of css.
More on this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

Comment: it could be a good idea but I want the "dots" like this "..." because for some Layout's reason it's more beautiful

Comment: Instead of using "..." scroll bar should be used. In case of "...", user will not be able to read the whole message even if he knows that the message displayed in div is clipped.

Comment: I know but I have a button next to the text like "See more". that's why I need the dots.

Comment: And I don't want to write manually the "..." for some modular reasons

Comment: This link provides describes functionality which you require.
http://thepugautomatic.com/octopress/2008/02/jquery-html-truncate/

Comment: it's really good but I have an external link, so it's not efficiant for me. Thanks you anyways