# CSS text-overflow: ellipsis; not working?

Tags: overflow, ellipsis, css

I don't know why this simple CSS isn't working...

```css
.app a {
  height: 18px;
  width: 140px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <a href="">Test Test Test Test Test Test</a>
</div>
```

Should cut off around the 4th "Test"

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802175/truncating-long-strings-with-css-feasible-yet

Comment: related: [Applying Ellipsis to Multiline Text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33058004/3597276)

Answer (score 1515, accepted):

`text-overflow:ellipsis;` only works when the following are true:

- The element's width must be constrained in `px` (pixels). Width in `%` (percentage) won't work.
- The element must have `overflow:hidden` and `white-space:nowrap` set.

The reason you're having problems here is because the `width` of your `a` element isn't constrained. You do have a `width` setting, but because the element is set to `display:inline` (i.e. the default) it is ignoring it, and nothing else is constraining its width either.

You can fix this by doing one of the following:

- Set the element to `display:inline-block` or `display:block` (probably the former, but depends on your layout needs).
- Set one of its container elements to `display:block` and give that element a fixed `width` or `max-width`.
- Set the element to `float:left` or `float:right` (probably the former, but again, either should have the same effect as far as the ellipsis is concerned).

I'd suggest `display:inline-block`, since this will have the minimum collateral impact on your layout; it works very much like the `display:inline` that it's using currently as far as the layout is concerned, but feel free to experiment with the other points as well; I've tried to give as much info as possible to help you understand how these things interact together; a large part of understanding CSS is about understanding how various styles work together.

Here's a snippet with your code, with a `display:inline-block` added, to show how close you were.

```css
.app a {
  height: 18px;
  width: 140px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <a href="">Test Test Test Test Test Test</a>
</div>
```

Useful references:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: What if I can't use set width due to responsive design?

Comment: Note that max-width also works. This helped me because I had an icon that had to hug the end of text regardless of its span's width. (Otherwise the icon would be floating out to the right if the text did not take up the span's full width)

Comment: For responsive behaviour simply change inline-block to block, e.g. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsmuydj3/)

Comment: `white-space: nowrap`... that was it for me.

Comment: Ran into this whilst trying to contain the spill in table cells. A minor correction - the width needs to be constrained by `em` works just as well as `px`.  However, `overflow:hidden` must be specified.

Comment: Note: `white-space: nowrap` is actually not necessary. We can still see the ellipses even without it. For multiple lines `text-overflow`, see [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines)

Comment: Not sure whether this is a recent change or not, but in Chrome 50 (beta) you don't have to set width to a px value -- "100%" also works. `white-space: nowrap` is required though.

Comment: You **do not** need to set a fixed `width` at all. All you need to do is set a `white-space: nowrap;` and it works just fine.

Comment: @adamj I used `width:100%` but required `position:static` as well (`absolute` did not work, I didn't try too many others)

Comment: Don't need to set a width. Works on chrome without it. Just needs to be a block element and static/relative positioning.

Comment: To overcome the percentage limitation, you can wrap it in `calc()` as in : `width: calc(90%)` (tested on chrome 63 and IE11)

Comment: `calc()` wasn't an option when the question was asked. But yes, it does indeed solve a lot of problems like this.

Comment: For me, adding the following css to my div, did the trick:
`display: block; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Like other people have mentioned here in the comments, explicitly set percentage widths are now working but I'm unsure of the browser support, when in doubt, just assume it's broken for IE 10 and below.

Comment: display:flex also doesn't appear to support text-overflow:ellipsis. Changing to display:block shows the ellipsis.

Comment: It didn’t work for me because it was `display: flex`, I set `display: block` and everything was fine.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov - yep, bear in mind that this answer was written before `display:flex` was a thing.  :-)

Comment: I don't know if there was an update from the time you wrote this answer to the present date. But, it does work with `%` on width. Only thing I had to make sure was about `overflow: hidden; white-space:nowrap`.

Comment: the part about the width isn't true

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge you can set max-width as 0 for responsive one. reference here - https://css-tricks.com/tale-width-max-width/

Comment: I also found using `display: flex` defeats `text-overflow: ellipsis` setting.

Comment: In some cases, you only need to add `overflow: hidden` to the **container** element.

Comment: If you can't specify the width in pixels as @Spudley says, you can still achieve the three dots by specifying min-width in pixels as well. Nice flex example: https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/

Comment: You **may** set the width in percent, but with **extra cautions**. An example for this condition is that if the inner div's width is set to 100%, but its parent has max-width 100px.

Comment: Note: - The bootstrap example of the *text-truncate* class has been used on the *col* class which uses width in "%". Also *white-space: nowrap* is not every time necessary but yes sometimes.

Comment: Just wanted to say[,](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/css/text-overflow-ellipsis-doesnt-work) these comments are great I learned so much about `text-overflow: ellipsis` from just this.

Comment: This answer got some wrong detail... You don't actually need to declaire a fixed px for width at all! I tested myself with no fixed width in flexbox, and it also works fine

Comment: Thanks, I used display: inline-block in a span with your answer.

Comment: I got it working without setting a set width in pixels. The outisde container has width in % and it constrains my text.

Answer (score 165):

The accepted answer is awesome. However, you can still use `%` width and attain `text-overflow: ellipsis`. The solution is simple:

```
display: inline-block; /* for inline elements e.g. span, strong, em etc */
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width: calc(80%); /* The trick is here! */
```

It seems whenever you use `calc`, the final value is rendered in absolute pixels, which consequentially converts `80%` to something like `800px` for a `1000px`-width container. Therefore, instead of using `width: [YOUR PERCENT]%`, use `width: calc([YOUR PERCENT]%)`.

Comment: Awesome, just adding that `overflow: hidden;` is also needed

Comment: This does not seem to be true in my case, I've got `width: calc(100% - 20px);` but no overflow is created.

Comment: Dynamic width, eg: `100%`, is possible. Also, please don't forget to add width in the parent component before applying this solution.

Answer (score 96):

So if you reach this question because you're having trouble trying to get the ellipsis working inside a `display: flex` container, try adding `min-width: 0` to the outmost container that's overflowing its parent even though you already set a `overflow: hidden` to it and see how that works for you.

More details and a working example on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/aj-foster/pen/emBYPW) by [aj-foster](https://github.com/aj-foster). Totally did the trick in my case.

Comment: Great solution - it's also the only one posted here that works for a `position: sticky` element within a `display: flex` container.

Comment: I had this problem on Firefox, Chrome was Ok. I had `display` set to `grid` on `body`. To fix this I had to set `min-length: 0;` on grid items (in my case children of body)

Comment: For an in depth explanation on "why this is necessary" I suggest to read [the following answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/1697459)

Comment: The most important thing is in the answer: `the outmost container that's overflowing`.
I had to add `min-width:0` to the top 2 containers on different levels. I spent 6 hours to realize it.

Comment: The explanation to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66689926/9157799

Comment: Note to self: Consider `overflow-wrap: break-word;` instead of ellipsis.

Comment: This is the best solution. Actually, one better, adding `flex-basis:0` to your element that needs the overflow ellipsis. This will make the element take up as much width as it needs, but not if it means overflowing the flex container

Comment: For me what worked was to make sure to place the `overflow:hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space:nowrap` directly on the flex child that I want to elipsis, instead of targetting the flex container.

Answer (score 37):

I have been having this problem and I wanted a solution that could easily work with dynamic widths. The solution use css grid.
This is how the code looks like:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.dynamic-width-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fixed-width-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="dynamic-width-child">
    iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii asdfhlhlafh;lshd;flhsd;lhfaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-width-child">Why?-Zed</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found that, if you have a hierarchy of children, you need to set the `dynamic-with-child` on all of them

Comment: `grid-template-columns` might need to be replaced with `grid-template-rows` based on requirement. Save that one change, this is the only answer that worked without any hitches or weird workarounds.

Answer (score 15):

I faced the same issue and it seems like none of the solution above works for Safari. For non-safari browser, this works just fine:

```
display: block; /* or in-line block according to your requirement */
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

For Safari, this is the one that works for me. Note that the media query to check if the browser is Safari might change over time, so just tinker with the media query if it doesn't work for you. With `line-clamp` property, it would also be possible to have multiple lines in the web with ellipsis, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp).

```
// Media-query for Safari-only browser.
@media not all and (min-resolution: 0.001dpcm) {
  @media {
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -webkit-box;
    white-space: normal;
  }
}
```

Comment: `display: block` did the trick for me (using Chrome), `<a>` tags are by default inline.

Answer (score 13):

Include the four lines written after the info for ellipsis to work

```
.app a
{
 color: #fff;
 font: bold 15px/18px Arial;
 height: 18px;
 margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 140px;

 /* 
 Note: The Below 4 Lines are necessary for ellipsis to work.
 */

 display: block;/* Change it as per your requirement. */
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: For a table cell the `display: block;` will break it so you need to use `max-width: 100px;`.  Note that `width` will *not* work.  No idea why not.

Answer (score 9):

Just add in the div containing that paragraph

```
white-space: nowrap 
width: 50px; 
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis; 
border: 1px solid #000000;
```

Answer (score 8):

Add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to your `#User_Apps_Content .DLD_App a`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BdQgB/1/)

Comment: I just checked and it is cutting off :/

Comment: you need ```text-overflow: ellipsis;``` not ```text-overflow: "...";```

Answer (score 7):

Also make sure `word-wrap` is set to *normal* for IE10 and below.

*The standards referenced below define this property's behavior as being dependent on the setting of the "text-wrap" property. However, wordWrap settings are always effective in Windows Internet Explorer because Internet Explorer does not support the "text-wrap" property.*

Hence in my case, `word-wrap` was set to *break-word* (inherited or by default?) causing `text-overflow` to work in FF and Chrome, but not in IE.

[ms info on word-wrap property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

`anchor`,`span`... tags are ***inline elements*** by default, In case of inline elements `width` property doesn't works. So you have to convert your element to either `inline-block` or `block level` elements

Answer (score 3):

In **[bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow)**, you can add a `.text-truncate` class to truncate the text with an ellipsis.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Inline level -->
<span class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width: 250px;">
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

MUST contain

```
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
```

MUST NOT contain

```
display: inline
```

SHOULD contain

```
position: sticky
```

Answer (score 2):

Please also ensure, that the immediate enclosing element has a fixed width, and the span where you want to apply ellipsis , has a `display:block`

Answer (score 2):

For me I wasn't setting it inside the inner div I was setting it in outer div so even though I had nowrap, overflow:hidden, and a set width it wasn't working. The code looked like:

```
<div className="outer">
  <ToolTip>
    <div className="inner"> long content needing to be cut
    </div>
  </ToolTip>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add one line css:

```
.app a {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some long descriptions ellipse(take only one lane) while being responsive, so my solution was to let the text wrap(instead of `white-space: nowrap`) and instead of fixed width I added fixed height:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  // OPTIONAL LINES
  width: 75%;
  background: green;
  //  white-space: normal; default
}
```

```html
<span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi quia quod reprehenderit saepe sit. Animi deleniti distinctio dolorum iste molestias reiciendis saepe. Ea eius ex, ipsam iusto laudantium natus obcaecati quas rem repellat temporibus! A alias at, atque deserunt dignissimos dolor earum, eligendi eveniet exercitationem natus non, odit sint sit tempore voluptate. Commodi culpa ex facere id minima nihil nulla omnis praesentium quasi quia quibusdam recusandae repellat sequi ullam, voluptates. Aliquam commodi debitis delectus magnam nulla, omnis sequi sint unde voluptas voluptatum. Adipisci aliquam deserunt dolor enim facilis libero, maxime molestias, nemo neque non nostrum placeat reprehenderit, rerum ullam vel? A atque autem consectetur cum, doloremque doloribus fugiat hic id iste nemo nesciunt officia quaerat quibusdam quidem quisquam similique sit tempora vel. Accusamus aspernatur at au
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add text ellipsis inside a flex element. Make sure either you pass `width` to the child element or simply add `max-width: 0`

Answer (score -3):

> Write these in your css rule.

```
display: block; /* or in-line block according to your requirement */
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: You can also look through this, https://jsfiddle.net/ManiAnand/5v6pfy9w/

Comment: If width can be specified doesn't make my answer wrong. All you just added display block in my answer, I have written a snippet, not the whole codes, so other things can be added but have nothing to do with the problem!!
Can you please specify how my answer is not correct?

Comment: The width needs to be specified as well as the display. If width a percentage or unspecified and not set to hard units, overflow will not be constrained and it won't work. See the accepted answer.

Comment: Width has already been set by the op. I gave snippet to add in his codes

Answer (score -9):

You can also add `float:left;` inside this selector:

```
#User_Apps_Content .DLD_App a
```