# Jquery - Detect Window Width

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this little script where i try to detect the window size to apply the limit of caracters of an element.

the problem the detection is not working. Always apply the limit of 150.

i have set an alert to look if detect or not, and now i´m sure that he is always apply the same.

can someone help me to find out what is wrong with this script?

**here is my code:**

```
$(function () {
        $(".block6 p").each(function (i) {
            len = $(this).text().length;
            if (len > 10) {
                if ($(window).width() <= 1280) {
                    $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 150) + '...');
                }
                else if ($(window).width() > 1280) {
                    $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 10) + '...');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: well, are you changing the width to more than 1280?

Comment: write `console.log($(window).width())` above the if condition. What does that give you? a jsfiddle would help us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code only runs once, on `document.ready`. You need to run the test every time the window is resized:

```
    $(window).on('resize',function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 1280) {
            $(".block6 p").each(function (i) {
                var len = $(this).text().length;
                if (len > 10) {
                    $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 150) + '...');
                }
            });
        } else { //if ($(window).width() > 1280) {
            $(".block6 p").each(function (i) {
                var len = $(this).text().length;
                if (len > 10) {
                    $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 10) + '...');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/6PQ4Q/

That said, you have a problem in that you're altering the text of each element directly, so switching back and forth by resizing the browser will be destructive. I suggest using [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working) instead if possible.

Comment: the problem is now that the script only work when i resize the window, but i want on load page.

Comment: can i do something like (document).load ??

Comment: Forgot you had that in the `<head>`. Fixed that too.

Comment: its working now.... you are the man...  heheh... thank you ver much for this great help...  +1