# Text-overflow ellipsis is not working for selected file name in <input type='file' /> in firefox. Please suggest solution

Tags: firefox, ellipsis, css, input-type-file

I am not able to find solution for applying "text-overflow:ellipsis" style to selected file name in `<input type='file'/>` in **Firefox browser**

I am applying css as follow

```
 .inp{
     display: inline-block;
    text-overflow:ellipsis
    -ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: normal;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width:16em;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing semi-colon after "ellipsis", but I think your problem may be in using "em" for width. Use a fixed or max width in pixels if you can. Plus, 16em is a humongous size, depending on what size it's based on.

An excellent explanation of your problem, probable causes, and solutions is here:

[CSS text-overflow: ellipsis; not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)

Comment: No I am getting this problem only for 'input type file' and on firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the width and this will wrap the text. This works well in firefox.

Comment: for better understanding it would be better if you added some sample code