# text-overflow is not working with my DOM structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/ysfqk9wL/2/

I made a demo up there. I am going for the itunes effect. When a title is too long and gets cut off. So when the user hovers over it will show the rest of the text.

I am using this:

```
    @mixin text-overflow() {
      -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
      -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
li p {
    width: 250%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    left:5px;
        @include text-overflow();
}
```

The JS is working just fine but in my CSS I want it to show "..." on the end.
I am using text-overflow: ellipse; but it is not working for me.

Any ideas? Please view the link.

Comment: They aren't working because you have Sass mixins here but you aren't importing Sass in your code, so the CSS doesn't know how to handle any of the @stuff.

Comment: Are you sure? If I inspect element and go to that element, the styles are there. Also, when I applied it as normal css, no change was made. Could you make a branch off my fiddle with your fix so I can better understand your statement?

Comment: The text also needs set to `white-space: nowrap;` for ellipsis.

Comment: I added both of your guys changes to http://jsfiddle.net/ysfqk9wL/4/ and no such luck

Comment: @Christian4423 I don't have a fix, I just don't see the Sass library imported anywhere, unless jQuery Edge includes it now?

Comment: No, if you go into the side nav on jsfiddle and select languages you can tell it to render sass

Comment: See this basic [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2zjr15gp/) of it, no animation.

Comment: @Pangloss Thank you so much! The client isn't too worried about the animation. That was me trying to go a little out of scope. This is more important as it was on the mockup. Thanks again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS text-overflow: ellipsis; not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)