# Prevent flex items from overflowing a container

Tags: css, flexbox

How do I make my flex item (`article` in this example), which has `flex-grow: 1;` **not** to overflow its flex parent/container (`main`)?

In this example `article` is just text, though it might contains other elements (`table`s, etc).

```css
main, aside, article {
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
main {
  display: flex;
}
aside {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
article {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x </aside>
  <article>don't let flex item overflow container.... y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y </article>
</main>
```

Comment: I had a pretty similar problem with a child table-responsive overflowing the flex item, the solution was to add `min-width: 0;` to the flex item.

Comment: I could kiss you @WashingtonGuedes your mention of min-width led me to this CSS Tricks article which describes how/why min-width solves the issue https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes which item do u add this to i can not seem to get this right

Comment: As a general answer to this question: Consider if using `display: grid` is viable alternative. It just seems to work out better for certain types of problem like this. Of course it wasn't viable when the question was asked but don't forget to consider it.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Your flex items have

```
flex: 0 0 200px; /* <aside> */
flex: 1 0 auto;  /* <article> */
```

That means:

- The `<aside>` will start at `200px` wide.

  Then it won't grow nor shrink.
- The `<article>` will start at the width given by the content.

  Then, if there  is available space, it will grow to cover it.

  Otherwise it won't shrink.

To prevent horizontal overflow, you can:

- Use `flex-basis: 0` and then let them grow with a positive `flex-grow`.
- Use a positive `flex-shrink` to let them shrink if there isn't enough space.

To prevent vertical overflow, you can

- Use `min-height` instead of `height` to allow the flex items grow more if necessary
- Use `overflow` different than visible on the flex items
- Use `overflow` different than visible on the flex container

For example,

```css
main, aside, article {
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
  min-height: 50px; /* min-height instead of height */
}
main {
  display: flex;
}
aside {
  flex: 0 1 200px; /* Positive flex-shrink */
}
article {
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* Positive flex-shrink */
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x </aside>
  <article>don't let flex item overflow container.... y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y </article>
</main>
```

Comment: it seems not gonna work if I have `<table>` inside the `<article>` even wrap the table with `div` and `overflow: auto;`

Comment: If you are dealing with many flex items overflowing container (instead of text), you should use [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)

Comment: @vee when you have a <table> to deal with the solution is to add min-width: 0 to the flex child containing the table, as explained above by Washington Guedes.

Comment: It does not work, it never works, tested on multiple websites. Your solution is fully wrong and should be removed.

Comment: @vee try setting `flex: 1 1 0; min-width: 0;` on `<article>` – had the same problem with `<table>` and it helped; see https://dev.to/martyhimmel/quick-tip-to-stop-flexbox-from-overflowing-peb

Comment: I've been using flexbox for years and still find all this incredibly confusing.

Comment: In Chrome, it seems this doesn't work. Horizontal scrollbars appear when you shrink the flexbox horizontally, after you pass the "preferred width" of the box, but before flex decides to wrap and put the entire box on another row. This is annoying me radically. I would simply expect flex to rather wrap the box than start putting scrollbars on it, it just feels buggy :)

Comment: Update to my comment above: also same in Safari. I think there is some magic decision that Flexbox uses when deciding to wrap a flex child to the next row or not, that I don't understand. I guess the situation is not exactly the same as in this question about shrinking elements but related.

Comment: Update again... I had misunderstood what flex-basis does I think. I specified it in pixels, as a hint, but it seems FlexBox takes it more seriously and relies more on that than the actual child content width in that case. Reverting it to "auto" allowed the child to avoid overflowing. Was not obvious (to me at least). Leaving my confused comments here if anyone else stumbles on it :)

Answer (score 562):

For me simply adding `min-width: 0;` to the overflowing div prevented the overflow:

```
article {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

**Explanation:**

`min-width` in a flex context: While the default `min-width` value is `0` (zero), for flex items it is `auto`. This can make block elements take up much more space than desired, resulting in overflow.

`min-width` is defined to win against competing `width` and `max-width`, meaning as soon as the element's width would shrink below its implicit auto width, `min-width:auto` will kick in and keep the element from shrinking.

The fix is obvious now: `min-width: 0`

It tells the browser that this element has no right to take up any minimum width, and now it will be rendered properly, taking up only as much width as is available.

A note about `flex-shrink`: While flex-shrink sounds like it could help here, it does not. The described issue is about element-sizing based on the element's content, while flex-shrink defines shrinkage relative to other flex elements in the same context. [Source](https://makandracards.com/makandra/66994-css-flex-and-min-width)

Comment: In other words, befause `display:flex;` results in `min-width:auto;`, then the element cannot shrink below it's requrested width, thus it will never create an overflow within itself.

Comment: @ZitRo and vxn see also the CSS Tricks article linked to in a comment on the OP by Josh Dean.

Comment: Just discovered this quirk on flexbox containers today when trying to let flexbox overflow-x scroll on small screens, that's one mystery solved.

Comment: Does not work with the code snippet provided

Comment: Oh my god, I was tearing my hair out over this quirk; thank you so much!

Comment: Oh the pain I went through until I found this random answer! Thank you!

Comment: It's so counter-intuitive i return to this answer very often)

Comment: This answer also helped me with a similar issue using CSS grid.

Comment: bro i love you, a beer is on me

Comment: Note: if you use `flex-direction: column;` the overflow is prevented with `min-height: 0;`

Comment: I've spent days on prompts for ChatGPT to just tell me how to friggin stop a flex-grow: 1 from growing beyond, and I was just one old fashion Google search away from finding out...

Answer (score 14):

One easy solution is to use `overflow` values other than `visible` to make the text flex basis width reset as expected.

1. Here with value `auto` the text wraps as expected and the article content does not overflow main container.
2. Also, the article `flex` value must either have a `auto` basis AND be able to shrink, OR, only grow AND explicit `0` basis

```css
main, aside, article {
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: auto; /* 1. overflow not `visible` */
}
main {
  display: flex;
}
aside {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
article {
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* 2. Allow auto width content to shrink */
  /* flex: 1 0 0; /* Or, explicit 0 width basis that grows */
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x </aside>
  <article>don't let flex item overflow container.... y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Downvote: bother explain? Running the snipper shows UI expected by OP?

Comment: This is the correct solution in case you have overflowing content, such as images or text with `white-space: nowrap`. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

If you want the overflow to wrap: `flex-flow: row wrap`

Answer (score 10):

I know this is really late, but for me, I found that applying `flex-basis: 0;` to the element prevented it from overflowing.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of `flex: 1 0 auto` just use `flex: 1`

```css
main, aside, article {
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
main {
  display: flex;
}
aside {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
article {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x </aside>
  <article>don't let flex item overflow container.... y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y </article>
</main>
```

Comment: To clarify, `flex: 1` is like `flex: 1 1 0`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think I had the wrong mental modal for what `flex-shrink` is then since I suppose I *do* want it to shrink. Also @Oriol I think `flex: 1` is `flex: 1 1 auto`.

Comment: @philfreo No, it is `flex: 1 1 0`. Src: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property

Comment: Hmm, why does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex show `auto` as the initial value for the 3rd param?

Comment: Chrome 68 shows 0% as default flex-basis value when using `flex: 1`

Comment: @philfreo `auto` is the initial value for `flex-basis`. If you say `flex: 1` you are in fact overriding that initial value to `0`, even though the `0` is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

It's not suitable for every situation, because not all items can have a non-proportional maximum, but slapping a good ol' `max-width` on the offending element/container can put it back in line.

Answer (score 1):

`max-width` works for me.

```css
aside {
  flex: 0 1 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

Variables of CSS pre-processors allows to avoid hard-coding.

```css
aside {
  $WIDTH: 200px;
  flex: 0 1 $WIDTH;
  max-width: $WIDTH;
}
```

`overflow: hidden` also works, but I lately I try do not use it because it hides the elements as popups and dropdowns.

Answer (score 1):

```
article { width: 0; }
```

it also works

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party here but here it how it works. the "parent" which has flex property decides how content will flow by default its sub divs will flow horizontally. you have to specify to flow vertically and then go from there. hope it helps.

```css
main, aside, article {
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
main {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
     flex-direction: column;
}
aside {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
article {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x </aside>
  <article>don't let flex item overflow container.... y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y </article>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to use `max-width: 0rem;` or in tailwindCSS `max-w-0`, the opposite of what the top-voted answer suggests.

```
<wrapper that is flex>
  <div className="flex max-w-0">
    overflowing content here
  </div>
</wrapper>
```