# Fill the remaining height or width in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 2 divs side-by-side in a flexbox. The right hand one should always be the same width, and I want the left hand one to just grab the remaining space. But it won't unless I specifically set its width.

So at the moment, it's set to 96% which looks OK until you really squash the screen - then the right hand div gets a bit starved of the space it needs.

I guess I could leave it as it is but it feels wrong - like there has to be a way to say:

> *the right one is always the same; you on the left - you get everything that's left*

```css
.ar-course-nav {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 12px 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.ar-course-nav:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="ar-course-nav" style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between;">
  <div style="width:96%;">
    <div style="overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis;">
      <strong title="Course Name Which is Really Quite Long And Does Go On a Bit But Then When You Think it's Stopped it Keeps on Going for even longer!">
                Course Name Which is Really Quite Long And Does Go On a Bit But Then When You Think it's Stopped it Keeps on Going for even longer!
            </strong>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; display:flex; justify-content:space-between;">
      <div style="color:#555555; margin-right:8px; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis;" title="A really really really really really really really really really really really long department name">
        A really really really really really really really really really really really long department name
      </div>
      <div style="color:#555555; text-align:right; white-space:nowrap;">
        Created: 21 September 2016
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left:8px;">
    <strong>&gt;</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could also use `grid-template-rows/columns`

Answer (score 798, accepted):

Use the `flex-grow` property to make a flex item consume free space *on the main axis*.

This property will expand the item as much as possible, adjusting the length to dynamic environments, such as screen re-sizing or the addition / removal of other items.

A common example is `flex-grow: 1` or, using the shorthand property, `flex: 1`.

Hence, instead of `width: 96%` on your div, use `flex: 1`.

---

*You wrote:*

> So at the moment, it's set to 96% which looks OK until you really squash the screen - then the right hand div gets a bit starved of the space it needs.

The squashing of the fixed-width div is related to another flex property: `flex-shrink`

By default, flex items are set to `flex-shrink: 1` which enables them to shrink in order to prevent overflow of the container.

To disable this feature use `flex-shrink: 0`.

For more details see ***The `flex-shrink` factor*** section in the answer here:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

---

Learn more about flex alignment along the *main axis* here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Learn more about flex alignment along the *cross axis* here:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

Comment: I had the same situation and using `flex-grow: 1` was not having the same effects than `flex: 1`. Do you maybe know why is it different? (I fixed my problem with the latter, thx)

Comment: With `flex-grow: 1`, the `flex-basis` property remains at `auto`, its default value. With `flex: 1`, the `flex-basis` property changes to `0`. See my answer here for an in-depth review: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276 @WhGandalf

Comment: flex-shrink was the key for me :)

Comment: Not only this but you'll also want to prevent an element from taking more space than is available using `min-width: 0` (or `min-height:0` is flex direction column), or else it will overflow beyond the available space in the layout, which is super weird honestly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66689926/454780

Comment: But the children of an item will ignore the parent size, even with width/height to 100%.
My case is about height: flex container with direction as column > Item with flex grow to 1 > child with height: 100%, height 100% is ignored.

Answer (score 109):

Basically I was trying to get my code to have a middle section on a 'row' to auto-adjust to the content on both sides (in my case, a dotted line separator). Like @Michael_B suggested, the key is using `display:flex` on the row container and at least making sure your middle container on the row has a `flex-grow` value of at least 1 higher than the outer containers (if outer containers don't have any `flex-grow` properties applied, middle container only needs 1 for `flex-grow`).

Here's a pic of what I was trying to do and sample code for how I solved it.

[image]

```css
.row {
  background: lightgray;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
  margin-top:5px;
}
.left {
  background:lightblue;
}
.separator{
  flex-grow:1;
  border-bottom:dotted 2px black;
}
.right {
  background:coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="right">Right With Text</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">Left With More Text</div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">Left With Text</div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="right">Right With More Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 20):

Use this two lines for the element in the flex container:

```
flex-grow: 1; // Fill remaining space
min-width: 0; // Don't use more space than available
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but Michael Benjamin's answer fixed this for - a few years ago :-)

Comment: Thanks you're a life saver! I've been looking for this the entire day long.