# make full area in clickable flex container - flex itemized anchor tags to fill their available space in an unordered list?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider the following example below:

```css
.links {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid gray;
}

.links ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-content: stretch;
    }
    
.links li {
        padding: 10px 0 10px;
}

.links a {
        font-family: ralewayLight, sans-serif;
        padding: 10px 0 10px;
}

.links a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

On hover, I need to have the black area extend in it's available space so that when hovered, the black will extend on the left and right beyond the constraints of the `<a>` tag and meet to the other tag, so everything is spaced evenly and that the entire area is clickable.

I do this (I think with justify-content: space-evenly; but I now want to demonstrate that in color).

[Make div fill remaining *horizontal* space in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745051/make-div-fill-remaining-horizontal-space-in-flexbox)

```css
.links {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid gray;
}

.links ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-content: stretch;
    }
    
.links li {
        padding: 10px 0 10px;
}

.links a {
        font-family: ralewayLight, sans-serif;
        padding: 10px 0 10px;
        flex-grow: 1;
}

.links a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The hover state still stays in the constricted area.

How do I get it so that on hover, the black is evenly distributed across each item and that on hover the whole area is clickable?

Besides `flex-grow: 1;` I tried:

1. `align-items: stretch;`

DId not work

2. Adding a specific width to the flex children

Seemed to break the flexbox container

3. `align-content: stretch;`

Did not work

How do I get flex itemized anchor tags to fill their available space in an unordered list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `flex-grow: 1;` to your `li` element, center your `<a>` tag and make it a block-level element:

```css
.links {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 1px solid gray;
}

.links ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   align-content: stretch;
}
    
.links li {
   padding: 10px 0 10px;
   flex-grow: 1; /* add this */
}

.links a {
   font-family: ralewayLight, sans-serif;
   padding: 10px 0 10px;
   flex-grow: 1;
   display: block; /* add this */
   text-align: center; /* add this */
}

.links a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: @kawnah Glad I could help!

Comment: Instead of adding `flex: 1 1 auto`, why not add only what is actually needed (`flex-grow: 1`)? The other additions are extraneous.

Comment: That is true @AndyHoffman, I have edited my answer accordingly. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @AndyHoffman the key takeaway here was that the a tags needed to be block.

Comment: @kawnah That's simply untrue. Removing `flex-grow: 1` from the `<li>` will make the answer wrong. Go test it for yourself. The key takeaway is that both changes were needed.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping things simple, you need to add 3 lines of `CSS`. Apply `flex-grow: 1` to `.links li`. The anchors within them (which are *not* flex children) should be centered, `block` level elements.

```css
.links {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.links li {
  padding: 10px 0 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.links a {
  font-family: ralewayLight, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 0 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.links a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjczvLs0/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you would like to make it smooth you would need to give every child the 100% width and height of its father container, so the anchor background hover effect covers the full width of the container.

Here is the CSS:

```css
   * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .links {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        height: 80px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .links ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .links li {
        display: flex;
        flex-grow: 1;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .links a {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-family: ralewayLight, sans-serif;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .links a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #000;
    }
    a, li, ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I needed! (And I believe actually answers the question?)