# How to overlap the table(td) text without using position property

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

Here, I'm having issues with the table in display *`inline-block`* property. In my scenario, I need to add 2 spans and text inside the `td` element. When I use it the text wrapped into the next line. **Here I need the text overlap into the span, i.e., the spans should not be disturbing the `td`'s text content**. I don't want to use position property. Here is my simple demo.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 200px;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

span.leftspan {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

span.rightspan {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="leftspan"></span><span class="rightspan"></span>12</td>
    <td><span class="leftspan"></span><span class="rightspan"></span>25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the demo 2 numbers (12, 25) shouldn't wrap into the next line. I need to achieve this **without position** property.

Answer (score -1):

Using `display:flex` on the td element and `flex-grow: 1` in the element containing the number will make this element to fill the rest of the space on the parent td element. then you can make them overlap using a translateX transform. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745051/make-div-fill-remaining-horizontal-space-in-flexbox) for extra info about how flex and flex-grow.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 200px;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
}

span.leftspan {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

span.rightspan {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

span.rest {
  flex-grow: 1;
  transform: translateX(-100%)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="leftspan"></span><span class="rightspan"></span><span class="rest">12</span></td>
    <td><span class="leftspan"></span><span class="rightspan"></span><span class="rest">25</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: text content doesn't overlap the span. I need to overlap text into the span element.

Comment: I have updated the answer to make then overlap using `transform: translateX`

Answer (score -1):

Added `Div`, and added style for `Div`

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 200px;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

table tr td div {
  display: flex;
}

span.leftspan {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

span.rightspan {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span class="leftspan"></span><span class="rightspan"></span>12
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span class="leftspan"></span><span class="rightspan"></span>25
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I dont want to wrap spans with div