# How to make a div occupy all available remaining horizontal space without specifying its width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to create two divs: one (on the right) small, with short texts that don't wrap, and the other (on the left) bigger, occupying the remaining space of the screen, and wrapping the text where needed. I'm trying the following:

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
#divL {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
#divR {
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='divL'>
a short text
</div>
<div id='divR'>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
</div>
```

So far, so good. But the left panel will increase together with the text, pushing the right panel out of screen when the text is too large:

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
#divL {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
#divR {
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='divL'>
very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text 
</div>
<div id='divR'>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
<p>list of items</p>
</div>
```

I don't want to specify fixed widths, because the right panel has variable width (never too big, only two or three words in each line). How can I achieve such a simple design? Is it possible without specifying fixed widths somewhere?

Comment: You'll need to specify a relative width at the very least.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, I won't. See the accepted answer.

Comment: Technically, `flex-grow: 1` is a relative width; it is relative to the other boxes in the flex container, but whatever.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37745051/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
flex: 1 0 auto;
```

This is shorthand for:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: auto;
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

The problematic part is `flex-shrink: 0`. This says that the left div shouldn't shrink at all.

Instead, try:

```
flex: 1 1 auto;
```

Going a step further: the default value of `flex-shrink` is `1` and of `flex-basis` is `auto`. If 2 out of the 3 properties have default values, I wouldn't use the shorthand `flex` at all. I'd just specify the one property you need to NOT be default:

```
flex-grow: 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! What was confusing me is that in my real example the text is inside a div, which is inside another div, and both need `flex-grow: 1`. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Is that what do you want?

```css
    html,body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    body {
      display: flex;
    }
    #divL {
      background-color: green;
      flex: 1;
    }
    #divR {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div id='divL'>
    very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text 
    </div>
    <div id='divR'>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    <p>list of items</p>
    </div>
```