# Flexbox inside Details Summary

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to place a flexbox which spans the full container width inside a Details-Summary block but cannot quite figure out how to set the width of the flexbox.

Here is a minimal example:

```css
summary > div {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: calc(100% - 1.32em); /* chrome */
  width: calc(100% - 1.37em); /* firefox */
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <div><div>Flex-Item Summary</div></div>
  </summary>
  Detail Text Here
</details>
```

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/hokiedsp/pen/ExPNXEd)

By setting the flexbox `width` to `100%`, it (as expected) spans the entire summary container, thus placed on the next line. I was able to dynamically calculate the width with an arbitrary offset but it varies among user agents. Is there any way to make this browser-independent?

I've played around with psudo-elements (`summary::after` for FF and `-webkit-details-marker` for Chrome) but I couldn't get anywhere.

TIA

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to set a width.

Just set the parent to `display: flex` and the `div` to `flex-grow: 1`. Now it will consume the free space, whatever that may be.

```css
summary {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* keeps arrow vertically centered */
  background-color: red;
}

summary > div {
  flex-grow: 1; /* consumes free space */
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <div>
      <div>Flex-Item Summary</div>
    </div>
  </summary>
  Detail Text Here
</details>
```

[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/678789asdflu/pen/Rwroxoo)

More details here: [Make div fill remaining *horizontal* space in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37745051/3597276)

Comment: Setting summary display to flex kills the arrow in Firefox. So this solution is a no-go...