# Display content in between two div elements via CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I'd like to display some "dots" in between a label and a price, like this:

```
from..........£2,000.49
total........£20,000.00
```

However, the dots must "adapt/reduce/increase", if the length of the price increases.  (Like in the example above), as the prices are dynamic and not static/hardcoded.

I thought I would try this with flex.  I have a working example below, where I have two columns, in two rows.

There is no width on the .`price-big` class, so the width of these divs increases/decreases, with the length of the numbers.

I am then adding the dots to the `label` class.  However, this then pushes my divs onto separate lines/stacked, like in the example below.

```
.label {
    content: ".............................................";
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this, would be helpful as I'm kinda getting stuck on this one.

Thank you,
Reema

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: baseline;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 200px;
}

.label {
    font-size: 14px;
    /* flex: 0 50%; */
    flex-basis: 50%;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px red solid;
    /* width: 100%; */
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.label:after {
    content: ".............................................";
}


.price-big {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px red solid;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="label">price</div>
  <div class="price-big total">£2,000.49</div>
  <div class="label">total</div>
  <div class="price-big">£20,000.00</div>
</div>
```

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52711235/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes and no,  it requires to modify HTML's op ;) but flex can indeed do the job ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may combine float and flex to modify the formating context layout of the non floatting element and use a pseudo to fill that empty space inside it:

your CSS code modified :

```css
.main {
    /*display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: baseline;*/
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 200px;
    overflow:hidden; /* because of the float label */
}

.label {
    font-size: 14px;
    /* flex: 0 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1; */
    border: 1px red solid;
    /* width: 100%; 
    text-align: left;*/
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top:0.4em;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
 


.price-big { 
    border: 1px red solid; 
    font-size: 20px;
    display:flex;
}
.price-big:before {
content:'';
border-bottom:dotted;
margin-bottom:0.2em;
flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="label">price</div>
  <div class="price-big total">£2,000.49</div>
  <div class="label">total</div>
  <div class="price-big">£20,000.00</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Omg, I literally figured out the answer one minute after posting this.  I added `overflow: overlay;` to the `label` class:

```
.label {
    font-size: 14px;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px red solid;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: overlay; <--- added this
}
```

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: baseline;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 200px;
}

.label {
    font-size: 14px;
    /* flex: 0 50%; */
    flex-basis: 50%;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px red solid;
    /* width: 100%; */
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: overlay;
}

.label:after {
    content: ".............................................";
}


.price-big {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px red solid;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="label">price</div>
  <div class="price-big total">£2,000.49</div>
  <div class="label">total</div>
  <div class="price-big">£20,000.00</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow: overlay;` only works with webkit ;) and shows a scrollbar https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiXb8.jpg

Comment: @G-Cyrillus - Thank you for spotting this G!  Which browser did you use?

Comment: Version 87.0.4280.88 (Build officiel) (64 bits) windows 10 ;)