# How to separate two text with dotted line horizontally ie: text1...........text2

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to do a table of points like this without having to write manually the dots, because the items will be dynamic and they wont have the same size in characters, is there a way to achieve this with CSS? I'm using bootstrap 4 as base.

[click me for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGP2I.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `dashed` parameter in `border` rule to `hr` tag. For example - `border: 1px dashed white;`

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52711235/8620333

Comment: thanks, that will help