# How to add a specific amount of periods to list item?

Tags: html, css, list, bulletedlist

I'm making a menu for that currently looks like this...

[list item without periods/bullets.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O5Vo.png)

When what I want is to add periods between the name and the price depending on the space between them like this

[list item with periods.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3fB0.png)

As you can see, the periods don't go all the way to the the item's name.
How would I connect them together??

This is my HTML:

```
<li>
  <div>
    <span>Number</span><h4>Name</h4>
  </div>
    <h4>Price</h4>
</li>
```

Comment: It looks like "css dot leader" yields some useful web search results. (It took some digging before I found a search term I was satisfied with.)

Comment: Could you add your CSS - in particular, how are you positioning the price?

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52711235/8620333

Comment: @AHaworth Haworth  I'm using Bootstrap.  It's a span aligned to the end.

Answer (score -1):

you need to make a css rule like this:

```css
.your-dots-parent::before{
  content: '. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .";
  /* center it however it fits */
}
```

Use `&middot;` · for a dot or `&bull;` • for a thicker one

here's a link that you might find helpful
https://markentier.tech/posts/2021/03/responsive-toc-leader-lines-with-css/