# How to fill all available space with flex box

Tags: css, angular, sass, flexbox

[Image of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNGqS.png) I have three flex containers and I want to get them to fill out the space available in the most efficient way possible. I want the toggles below the heading to be directly next to the heading instead of on the next line to save space on smaller screens.

This is what my code currently looks like.

HTML:

````html
<header class="grid-header">
  <h1 class="app-heading-5">Sample Report</h1>
  <div class="grid-toolbar">
    <form class="form" [formGroup]="form">
      <mat-slide-toggle
        class="align-self-center"
        formControlName="groupByCountry"
        color="primary"
        [labelPosition]="'before'"
      >
        Country
      </mat-slide-toggle>
      <mat-slide-toggle
        class="align-self-center"
        formControlName="showChart"
        color="primary"
        [labelPosition]="'before'"
      >
        Chart
      </mat-slide-toggle>
      <kendo-floatinglabel class="filter-lg" text="Filter by Country...">
        <kendo-multiselect
          fillMode="flat"
          formControlName="country"
          [data]="countries$ | async"
          [filterable]="true"
          [valueField]="'fmsCountryCode'"
          [textField]="'narr'"
          [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings"
        >
        </kendo-multiselect>
      </kendo-floatinglabel>
      <kendo-floatinglabel text="From Yr...">
        <kendo-combobox
          fillMode="flat"
          formControlName="fromYear"
          [data]="expYears$ | async"
          [filterable]="true"
          [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings"
        ></kendo-combobox>
      </kendo-floatinglabel>
      <kendo-floatinglabel text="To Yr...">
        <kendo-combobox
          fillMode="flat"
          formControlName="toYear"
          [data]="expYears$ | async"
          [filterable]="true"
          [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings"
        ></kendo-combobox>
      </kendo-floatinglabel>
      <kendo-floatinglabel class="filter-md" text="Filter by Part Name...">
        <kendo-combobox
          fillMode="flat"
          formControlName="partName"
          [data]="partNames$ | async"
          [filterable]="true"
          [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings"
        ></kendo-combobox>
      </kendo-floatinglabel>
    </form>
    <button
      [disabled]="disableExport$ | async"
      kendoButton
      [primary]="true"
      (click)="exportFromApi()"
      title="Export to Excel"
    >
      Export
      <fa-icon [icon]="faFileExcel" size="lg"></fa-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</header>

SCSS```
.grid-header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-block: 0.5rem;

    .grid-toolbar,
    .form {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap: 1rem;
      align-items: flex-start;

      kendo-floatinglabel {
        width: 12.5rem;
      }

      .k-input {
        width: 12.5rem;
      }
    }

    button {
      align-self: center;
    }
  }
````

Comment: Have you tried using `flex-grow`? Here is a good stack answer for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745051/fill-the-remaining-height-or-width-in-a-flex-container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill the remaining height or width in a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745051/fill-the-remaining-height-or-width-in-a-flex-container)

Comment: Your current DOM structure makes this virtually impossible. As a rule of thumb: place all elements you want to _flex-arrange_ into the same container. That is currently not the case. You could move your `h1` heading into the `form` to rectify that.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the h1 has the display: inline-block property and also it would help to add a width to grid-header.