# how to make first column in a row sticky when scrolling horizontal using flex layout?

Tags: css, flexbox, position

how to make first column in a row sticky when scrolling horizontal using flex layout ?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: auto
}

.first-column {
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  background: gray;
}

.second-column {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first-column">
    <blockquote><i>Please, make me fixed!</i></blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="second-column">
    hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are
    u?hello How are u?
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a row inside a *ngFor(loop). So there can be multiple such rows like a table structure.I want the second div appear scroll beneath first column when scrolling horizontal and usual vertical scroll

Comment: why not fixed position ? or make the scroll in the second column instead of the whold wrap

Comment: Since you, in a comment at my now deleted answer, wrote _"When we scroll vertical, we need both columns in same line(first-column and second-column). Which is not happening if we are giving position:fixed"_, it appears the question lacks info for us to be able to give a proper answer. Based on that I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Its very simple bro as u mentioned in the question use `position:sticky` Css to left div 

 See the snippet below

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: auto
}

.first-column {
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  background: gray;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.second-column {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first-column">
    <blockquote><i>Please, make me fixed!</i></blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="second-column">
    hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are u?hello How are
    u?hello How are u?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Aravind for your reply. It would be great if you can provide some solution that will work in IE as well. Thank u

Comment: for IE you can use `position:fixed` as mentioned in other solutions

Comment: Wow this is great! I had no idea you could do this...thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a `z-index` on the first column to make sure it's on top of the other columns when you scroll.

Comment: Thanks, still useful now! In case somebody tries and struggles: I had to set flex-shrink: 1 on the non-sticky column (`flex: 0 0 auto`) and set its `min-width: 0` to prevent getting too large, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230944/prevent-flex-items-from-overflowing-a-container