# Fill remaining viewport space with a canvas (flexbox + three.js)

Tags: css, flexbox, three.js, html5-canvas

I'm using three.js to render to a canvas. I would like to have one `div` positioned above the canvas and another below. The canvas should fill the remaining space in between (even if it means the canvas changes aspect ratio whenever the viewport size changes, that's okay). The 3 elements together should fill 100% of the viewport at all times, but not exceed it and cause scrollbars to appear.

In case it's not clear, here's a gif I made (which uses a static image instead of a canvas) demonstrating exactly what I want to achieve:

[image: example]

I figured this would be a straightforward flexbox layout, but I can't seem to get it to work. Either scrollbars appear, or the bottom element gets pushed beyond the viewport. Here's one of my attempts (click Run code snippet > Full page):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas, antialias: true });
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
camera.position.z = 5;
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '#ff0000' });
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

requestAnimationFrame(render);

function render() {
  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;

  if (needResize) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  }

  return needResize;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.top, .bottom {
  padding: 10px;
}

.middle {
  flex: 1;
}

.middle canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="middle">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>

<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@v0.155.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@v0.155.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module">
  import * as THREE from 'three';
  window.THREE = THREE;
</script>
```

Strangely, if you change the `flex-direction` to `row`, you'll see it works exactly how I want it to, but horizontally. I would simply like it to work vertically. Is it possible?

Comment: But the canvas changes size because you call `resizeRendererToDisplaySize()` so since the height depends on the width, the bottom gets pushed or pulled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66689926). Since the `flex-direction` is `column`, the `min-height` of the middle element needs to be set to zero.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas, antialias: true });
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
camera.position.z = 5;
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '#ff0000' });
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

requestAnimationFrame(render);

function render() {
  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;

  if (needResize) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  }

  return needResize;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.top, .bottom {
  padding: 10px;
}

.middle {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;
}

.middle canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="middle">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>

<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@v0.155.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@v0.155.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module">
  import * as THREE from 'three';
  window.THREE = THREE;
</script>
```