# big text shoud be hidden for specific dimension

Tags: html, css, text

I have < p > tag and text there. 
Css:

```
p {
   max-height: 250px;
}
```

I want to make my text hide last word which can't fit in 250px of height and change it to "...". 
I have tried it:

```
p {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: hidden;
}
```

It worked but not as I want. It hide word which can't fit in the first line, but not the the 250px of height. Is there anyway to do so? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS text-overflow: ellipsis; not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the overflow-y property to hide the y-axis.

More about [overflow-y](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp).

CSS

```
p {
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>Some text goes here</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help sure

```
p{ 
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
}
```