# text-overflow:ellipsis css property not working in firefox, prev solution on stackoverflow is also not working

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I have used bootstrap media classes, i want to break in new line my title and description(clamp and place ellipsis if it exceeds width), i have used following css properties on  and

tags as well but it is not working i.e.

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow:hidden;
```

title is overflowing from div, i just want to fit it in width by applying above css. it is working fine in chrome. but not in firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the following definitions on the inner DIV:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
```

- "width" can be whatever you need, as long as it's definitive (px or %). Otherwise, the "ellipsis" effect will not work, because the browser doesn't know where the container "ends" and that the content is overflowing from this point on.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working) **ensure that your text is constrained** by making the element, or its parent, be `display:block` or `display:inline-block`, and have a `width` or `max-width` setting (not in `%`).

There are some other methods that you can try on that page.