# ion-input: overflow: hidden !important text-overflow: ellipsis ; not working for me

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have ion input with this css classes ind it is not working.

I tried all the solutions [in this link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)

and it still not working
This is my code:

html:

```
<ion-input 
    placeholder="{{data.IncentiveText | translate}}" (input)="updateSearch()" 
    [(ngModel)]="autocomplete.query" 
    [id]="data.FieldName" 
    [type]="text" 
    name="data.FieldName" 
    class="search"></ion-input>
```

css:

```
.search{
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    margin-top: 30px;
    white-space:nowrap !important;
    display:block !important;
    float:left;
    position: static;
}
```

Do you have any solution?

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: Do you want text inside search input to have three dot when overflow?

Comment: @Biswajit :yes. exactly.

Comment: My friend no one do this. I have never seen this. You cant put ... not with css inside input but you may be do using javascript. But i advice it is not wise because user might need to scroll inside input for full text line if it overlap. But if u do so user will find half text. Smile!