# String limit lines JS

Tags: javascript, dom, text-manipulation

I was looking other answers, and they are all based on something like this:

```
.text-limit{
    line-height:20px;
    height: 20 * n. lines;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

However what i want i something like `Youtube` does, so if the text is longer than 2 lines, truncate it and add `...` at the end.
However, i was able to do it using `Node` on my terminal, because every char on the terminal has the same width, but on browser it's not true, so i was wondering if there was already something that can help me doing this.

Code i was using:

```
const nLines = ...;
const lineWidth = ...;
const charWidth = ...;
let text = "...";
text = text.substring(0, nLines * Math.floor(lineWidth / charWidth) - 3) + "..."
console.log(text);
```

Comment: don't do that with javascript  - its something you should do with css

Comment: @DanielA.White how are you going to add the `...` with css?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these styles.

```
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

Read about: [line-clamp](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/)

Comment: i can't make ti work, can you please give a more significant example please?

Comment: got it working with `overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;display: -webkit-box;-webkit-line-clamp: 2;  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;` however `-webkit-box-orient` is supported  in a very few browser, are there any alternatives?