# Nested flex-shrink not working on nested div

Tags: html, css

Having some trouble to make a nested div shrink in a flex scenario.

It's a simplification of [Material-UI chips](https://material-ui.com/components/chips/), the idea is the chips to shrink their text when a line is full.

A simplified div structure looks like (we want the inner span to shrink) :

```
<div class="papa">
  <div class="child child1">Fixed-<span class="span">This is a long text that we want to shrink with ellipsis</span>-End</div>
  <div class="child child2">Fixed-<span class="span">This is a long text that we want to shrink with ellipsis</span>-End</div>
  <div class="child child3">Fixed-<span class="span">This is a long text that we want to shrink with ellipsis</span>-End</div>
</div>
```

How to make the inner span to shrink when there is no avaible space ?

Code example :

https://codepen.io/iccube/pen/abBgayz

Answer (score 1):

Just give the div with the class `.child` the ellipsis prop (like this):

**LATER EDIT:** I edited the code. I replaced the span with a div. (You can replace the div back to a span and add `display: block` to the `.span` class. But this is cleaner I think.) Basically you have to make sure that the text container will have the desired width, and since you cannot provide a fixed value for the width, the text you want to be truncated should have `display: block`

```css
.papa {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
  background-color: red
    oveflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.child2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.child3 {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="papa">
  <div class="child child1">Fixed-<div class="span">This is a long text that we want to shrink with ellipsis</div>-End</div>
  <div class="child child2">Fixed-<div class="span">This is a long text that we want to shrink with ellipsis</div>-End</div>
  <div class="child child3">Fixed-<div class="span">This is a long text that we want to shrink with ellipsis</span>-End</div>
</div>
```

You can read  more about overflow ellipsis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)

Comment: Thanks, that was a trick ;-).  But, I forgot to add another element after the End (I've updated the question).  I just want the inner span to shrink...

Comment: Than you could take ssaakkaa ' s response and add 
  `display: flex;
  width: 33%;` 
 to the `.child` class and you should be good :D

Comment: Check the updated code from the answer please. If I understand correctly this should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify width of the ".child" elements so flex know what to do with them. Solution is very simple here is the code you need to change:

```
.child {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

one more thing if you need ".papa" element to have some max-width, you can just set the max-width like this:

```
.papa {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: red;
  //SET YOUR MAX WIDTH
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

EDIT:
If I understand you correctly you want this behaviour:
https://codepen.io/ssaakkaa/pen/mdOZaJO

for that, you need to set overflow:hidden on the child elements

Comment: It's chips, so they should be aligned left and  grow till they take the whole width. Than shrink. 33% will make the parent div divided in 3 equal parts

Comment: Sorry, one single line -> .papa {  flex-wrap: nowrap; }

Comment: yes, like Bercy said then... the child needs overflow: hidden attribute :)