# How can I fix rendering issue on safari while using nuxt?

Tags: safari, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I'm using Do Hyeon font and all browsers render fine except for Safari. It seems if text is too short or not upper case, safari ignores spaces. However, if I click or hover the text, it re-renders with space.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how can I solve this?

I already tried adding these css property but did not work.

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
-webkit-font-feature-settings: 'kern' 1;
```

[image]
[image]

(Second picture) When I selected text

Comment: Do you have an error in the console or anywhere at all?

Comment: Also, which version of Safari?

Comment: No I do not see anything in console. 

I see text with the space in dev tool but it is just rendering without space. And when click text itself, it fixes the problem.

<h3 class="text-2.4xl font-doHyeon | mb-3" data-v-216fe4ff="">
        Test Event
</h3>

Comment: I'm using Version 14.1.2 (16611.3.10.1.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was Safari issue but unfortunately, I could not find the reason why this is happening.

However, after testing some css properties, the one I am using for displaying ellipsis worked for this issue as well, so I will leave the code here in case someone is having the same issue.

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 10;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
max-height: 10rem;
```

Again, these properties are originally for ellipsis especially for safari:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61515590/12332180 but propbably, this is related to modifing the text that is why it is working for my situation as well.