# Ellipsis with transition

Tags: html, css, overflow, ellipsis

For a project, I'm trying to use the CSS property `text-overflow: ellipsis` in order to complete the following [animation](https://imgur.com/a/8R3LHRO). However, when I'm trying to apply this property, with `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: hidden`, on `.card-dish__info`, the three dots don't appear and the overflowing text is hidden behind the checkmark and price.

When I tried to apply this property on `.card-dish` and `.card-dish__byline`, the checkmark animation is directly blocked. I also tried another advice of limiting the `width` of `.card-dish__info`, but it also doesn't work...

Here is my code:

```css
.card-dish {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 340px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 13px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.card-dish__info {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.card-dish__heading {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.card-dish__byline,
.card-dish__price {
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: black;
}

.card-dish__check {
  display: flex;
}

.card-dish__price {
  margin: 34px 0 5px 0;
}

.card-dish__checkmark {
  background-color: #99e2d0;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 -61px 0 15px;
  transition: margin-right 1.5s;
}

.card-dish:hover .card-dish__checkmark {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/                  
             1f544e41e8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card-dish">
  <div class="card-dish__info">
    <h6 class="card-dish__heading">Herb-Encrusted Steak</h6>
    <p class="card-dish__byline">With delicately sliced and seasoned vegetables</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-dish__check">
    <p class="card-dish__price">40€</p>
    <div class="card-dish__checkmark">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thank in advance anyone who will take the time to help me.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the width of the `.card-dish__byline` doesn't decrease in order for the text-overflow to take place. You should also add the `text-overflow: ellipsis` to the `.card-dish__byline`. Add this to your css:

```
.card-dish__byline {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 280px;
  transition: width 1.5s;
}
.card-dish:hover .card-dish__byline {
  width: 230px;
}
```