# Tablesorter Filter column A by content of column B

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a tablesorter with some data.
I'm using Twig templates from Symfony Framework.

I'll make a basic example:

```
<table id="tablesorter" class="hideAtFirst tablesorter hover-highlight focus-highlight">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <thead class="tablesorter-blue" id="tablesorterHeader">
    <tr class="warning">
        <th class="text-center">ID</th>
        <th class="text-center" title="comment_short">Comment</th>
        <th class="filter-false hidden" title="comment"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- BODY -->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>This is a [...]</td>
            <td>this is a long comment</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I'm trying to display the content of 'comment' as a short text. For that I'm using slice but i want to still be able to sort by the full comment content from the short column.

If comment's value is 'This is a long test', the second column shows 'This is a [...]' and if i try to filter the table by the word 'test' it won't show the result.
The 3 column with the full text has to be hidden. How can i filter the second column with the content of the 3 one?

This is what I've tried:

```
widgetOptions: {
    resizable: true,
    resizable_widths: sizes,
    filter_defaultAttrib: 'data-value',
    filter_saveFilters: true,
    saveSort: true,
    filter_functions: {
        1: function (e, n, f, i) {
            const query = f.toLowerCase(); //filter content from short comment
            const columnIndex = i + 1; //long comment column

            // Use the content from short comment to filter results from long comment column
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to proceed or if I'm asking the wrong questions.

EDIT: Changed twig template to html. Now let's suppose that the short text comes from the query with something like SUBSTRING(comment, 10, LEN(comment) ).
To limit the text to 10 characters.

Comment: Did you already have a look into [ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)?

Comment: [ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working) is exactly was i was looking for and didn't even know of its existence. Thanks @DarkBee