# CSS how to continue the text without breaking into new line in a <div>

Tags: html, css

I just wonder how should I add to my div style to have the text continues with "..." instead of breaking into a new line like this:

[image: no line break]

my code is below, i would like that style to be with my porfolio-info div:

```
<div class="portfolio-wrapper">
    <div class="portfolio-single">
        <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <img src="image-link" alt="" height="300px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-info" style="border: 1px dotted gray; display: inline;">
        <h2>Text will be here</h2>
    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: That is done using `text-overflow: ellipsis` like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4JxBt/). All CSS properties mentioned in that fiddle are mandatory for it to work. I think this question is a duplicate and hence not adding as answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802175/truncating-long-strings-with-css-feasible-yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
.portfolio-info{ text-overflow: ellipsis ellipsis; text-align: center; }
```

**[Demo](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `.portfolio-info` to `display: block`, and set it's `white-space` to `no-wrap`, keeping the text in one line. You can't have block-level elements like `h2` in an inline element so I changed it to a `span`. You can then set a fixed or percentage-based width to keep that div in the container at a specified size. Then, all you need to do is just set the `.portfolio-info` to `text-overflow: ellipsis`, making the overflowing text end with an ellipsis character.

If possible, avoid using inline attributes like `height` and `style`, use plain CSS instead to keep the markup and the styling separate.

```
<div class="portfolio-wrapper">
    <div class="portfolio-single">
        <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/300" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-info">
        <span>Very long text that will likely overflow the container, making the text too long to fit into this square, meaning to goes to a new line</span>
    </div>
```

```
.portfolio-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
}
.portfolio-single {
    margin: 0px 0px 10px;
}
.portfolio-single,
.portfolio-thumb,
.portfolio-thumb img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.portfolio-info {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 300px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[JSFiddle of this example](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/Ab2Ku/)